# Ajax - jQuery - JSON - PHP login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Ok so I'm trying to create a login form for an iOS application using Phonegap. In order to have users sign in, I need to work around the SOP. I've tried a number of tutorials and examples, and I can't get any of them to work. This is what I have right now, I could use some pointers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#login").click(function() {

    var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        is_ajax: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response == 'success')
                $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#message").html("You have logged in successfully!");
                });
            else
                $("#message").html("Invalid username and/or password.");    
        }
    });

    return false;
});

});
</script>
```

------------ on doLogin.php -----

```
<?php

$is_ajax = $_REQUEST['is_ajax'];
if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)
{
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo')
    {
        echo "success"; 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: in what specific regard you are having the problem

Comment: ejn, try using your debugger to find the source of the problem yourself. Then, if you're still stuck, you'll have a much more *specific* question that you can ask here, and you'll likely get better answers and more help once you've narrowed the problem down yourself :)  Good luck!

Comment: sorry, i was just wondering if anyone could give me some suggestions as to what I should change. Im stuck with what you see and it does not work.

Comment: @ejn: Please be specific in what *specifically* doesn't work. What exactly happens, do you get any error messages, etc.

Comment: That' understandable, but keep in mind we're volunteers, so you should try, if possible, to narrow the question down yourself, or at least tell us where you think the problem is and provide lots of detail. I think you have a great start, just continue to edit if you think of more details. For instance, posting the error messages you're seeing can really go a long way to helping us help you. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

First thought: your code is less error prone when using curly braces for your conditionals

```
if(response == 'success')
    $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $("#message").html("You have logged in successfully!");
    });
else
    $("#message").html("Invalid username and/or password.");
```

could be

```
if(response == 'success') {
    $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
        $("#message").html("You have logged in successfully!");
    });
} else {
    $("#message").html("Invalid username and/or password.");    
}
```

A user here explains why this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125078/680578

Comment: Curly braceless conditionals work for a single *statement*, regardless of the number of lines.

Comment: interesting, i've confused *statement* with *lines*. I didn't know that until now. I usually operate with this type of understanding about braceless conditionals; http://stackoverflow.com/a/2125078/680578