# Convincing a colleague about their if not being nested

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, nested

One of my university colleagues, who has started programming this year, sometimes writes if statements like this:

```
if(something) doA();
else
    if(something2) doC();
    else doD();
```

He is conviced that the second `if-else` pair is treated as a single entity, and that it is in fact nested under the first `else`.

I'm, however, sure that his code is equivalent to:

```
if(something) doA();
else if(something2) doC();
else doD();
```

This shows that the second else is not actually nested, but on the same level as the first if. I told him he needs to use curly braces to achieve what he wants to.

*"But my code works as intended!"*

And indeed, it worked as intended. Turns out the behavior of the code was the same, even if the `else` was not nested.

Surprisingly, I have found myself unable to write a clear and concise example that shows different behavior between

```
if(something) doA();
else
    if(something2) doC();
    else doD();
```

and

```
if(something) doA();
else {
    if(something2) doC();
    else doD();
}
```

Can you help me find an example that will show my colleague the difference between using/not using curly braces?

Or is the incorrect-looking version always equivalent to the one with curly braces, in terms of behavior?

Comment: He's right, you're wrong. The `else` controls a single statement. Curly braces are just a way to make a group of statements act (syntactically) like a single statement. If you only want it to control a single statement, the curly braces normally accomplish nothing. That said, you're usually better off placing an `else if` without further indentation. In C++, indentation does not affect behavior of code.

Comment: you are both wrong, for different reasons.

Comment: A trailing else without an if is a syntax error and your language will (usually) let you know that. So if the second if else statement was not treated together, you would essentially have if else else, not being syntactically correct. i.e. if you had if else{ if } else, this would be an error.

Comment: in both cases if(something2 = false), doD() statement gets executed, and if(something=true) only DoA() is executed, so it's pretty much the same.

Comment: @alk: No dangling else here.

Comment: This question already answered at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets

Comment: this question already answered at this  [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets

Comment: Stop writing code like this.  *You* will be its victim in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Guess there's always more to learn! I've always written code interpreting `if-else`s as in my second code snippet. Anyway, I apologized to my colleague and told him he was right all along! :)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: The second code snippet is mathematically identical to the first; you could define a grammar and semantics in which `else if` was parsed as a statement after an `if` and the effect were the same as standard C. It is simply not the way C defines it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's what tricked me. I was so sure I was right because in all my years of programming I've always interpreted my `if-else` structures as in the second code snippet.

Comment: Braces are pretty expensive, it seems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per C 2011 6.8.4 1, the grammar for a *selection-statement* includes this production:

> *selection-statement*: **if** **(** *expression* **)** *statement* **else** *statement*

Per 6.8 1, a production for *statement* is:

> *statement*: *selection-statement*

Thus, in:

```
if(something) doA();
else
    if(something2) doC();
    else doD();
```

the indented **if** and **else** form a *selection-statement* that is the *statement* that appears in the **else** clause of the preceding *selection-statement*.

The productions I have shown show that this is a possible interpretation in the C grammar. To see that it is the only interpretation, we observe that the text in the **else** clause of the initial *selection-statement* must be a *statement*, because there is no other production in the C grammar that produces an **else** keyword. (This is most easily seen by searching the grammar in clause A.2. Due to its size, I will not reproduce it here.) So we know the **else** is followed by a *statement*. We can easily see that the statement is a *selection-statement*, since it begins with **if**. Then the only question remaining is whether the next **else** is part of that **if** statement or not. Per 6.8.4.1 3, “An **else** is associated with the lexically nearest preceding **if** that is allowed by the syntax.”

Comment: Thanks for the quote from the Standard. I apologized to my colleague and told him he was right all along! :)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Well, he is and he isn't.  His indentation does reflect how the compiler sees things, but not how humans understand them.  His indentation is bad programming practice.

Comment: The way your colleague writes code is wrong, because it is error prone. It is good for scientific interest that you found out what the code actually does, now you should tell him to always write conditionals using brackets.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I have not seen any study that would justify a dogmatic statement of style or of human perception in this. Sometimes ifs and elses are used in testing a chain of conditions, and aligning them portrays that. Sometimes ifs and elses are used in testing nested conditions, an indenting them portrays them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Which is more or less what I'm saying (or meaning to say).  When there is a chain of conditions, the `else if` should all be aligned, regardless of how the compiler views them.  Indentation is communication of intent to other human beings.

Answer (score 5):

Both structures come out to the same thing.  The compiler
effectively sees the code as:

```
if ( something ) {
    doA()
} else {
    if ( something2 ) {
        doC();
    } else {
        doD();
    }
}
```

In practice, however, there is no different between this and:

```
if ( something ) {
    doA();
} else if ( something2 ) {
    doC();
} else {
    doD();
}
```

The extra braces encapsulate a single statement, and you don't
actually need the braces when the `if` or the `else` controls
a single statement.  (My first example puts *every* statement
except the encompassing `if` in braces.)

Logically, programmers tend to thing along the lines of the
second; languages where some sort of bracing (`{}`,
`BEGIN`/`END` or indentation) is required almost always add an
`elsif` or `elif` keyword in order to permit this second form.
C and C++ (and Java, and C#, and...) don't, because the second
form works out without the extra keyword.

In the end, you don't want the extra indentation.  (I've cases
with fifteen or twenty successive `else if`.  That would make
for some serious indentation.)  On the other hand, you *do* want
the controlled statement on a separate line.  (Bracing is
optional: if your coding standard puts the brace on a separate
line, it's also conventional to suppress it if it only contains
a single statement.)