# Understanding local variable initialization

Tags: java, initialization

I'm reading J. Bloch's effective Java and now I'm in the section about intialization of local variables. Here is what he said:

> **Nearly every local variable declaration should contain an initializer.** If you don’t yet have enough in formation to initialize
>   a variable sensibly, you should postpone the declaration until you do.
>   ***One*** exception to this rule concerns try-catch statements.

So, what about the `if-else` statement? We need to initialize a variable only if some condition is satisfied, and intialize it in another way if it is not, like

```
MyClass mc = null;
if(cond)
   mc = new MyClass();
else
   mc = new MyClass(1);
//use mc
```

Since, it's not mentioned by J. Bloch, is it considered as a bad programming technique and should be avoided?

Comment: I'm not sure if the "One exception" is meant as "The only exception" or "One of the exceptions". I guess it's the latter.

Comment: @flashdrive2049 Maybe, but not in this section then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the cleanest way should be:

```
final MyClass mc;
if (cond) {
   mc = new MyClass();
} else {
   mc = new MyClass(1);
}
//use mc
```

Because the final keyword will make sure, that the variable will always be initialized only once (for detailed explanation, look in your book at **Item 15: Minimize mutability**, page ~73).

And this is what you can't do in usual try-catch statements.

Also it's more effective and failsafe to [always use curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets?lq=1).

Answer (score 2):

You had to initialize a variable no matter what before it can be used.

If compiler analysis detects that a variable is initialized before it may be used, you can define a variable without initialization.

For example

```
int a;
if (...) { a = 0; }
else { a = 1;}
```

would be fine. However

```
int a;
if (...) { a = 0; }
```

would result in a compiler error as the condition may not become true in which case 'a' remains uninitialized.

Personally I prefer the '?' operator for cases as shown in your code:

```
MyClass mc = cond ? new MyClass() : new MyClass(1);
```

If you need the reference 'mc' outside the scope where it is initialized (the if / else block) you have to do it that way. It do not know this being considered bad practice. However in your concrete case a better solution might be possible but that is difficult to say without knowing the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass mc = null;
```

**This is sort of redundant.** Because the variable `mc` any way going to initialize either in `if` or `else` clause. so you can avoid it.

If you were initializing two different objects in `if` and `else` part, then you should initialize it while declaring, so you know what to expect from a particular variable later in your program.

Answer (score 1):

If the use of variable is outside the `if-else` block your declaration is fine.

But in case you want to use the variable within `if-else` block you should declare and use it within the `if-else` block.

Scope of use should decide initialization and declaration of variable.