# Nesting default of while and for loop

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I was curious about what would be default nesting in the body of a for loop and while loop in cases with no brackets.

I.E.

```
while (condition) //without brackets
if (condition)
else
```

and

```
for (condition) 
if (condition)
else
```

versus

```
while (condition)
for (condition)
if (condition
else
```

I know that for loop will nest an else if there is an if within it's body whenever there is no bracket presented. What happens with a while loop? Would it be the same? And also, including a while and a for loop within the condition? Would it turn out something like

```
while (condition) {
   for (condition) {
       if (condition)
       else
   } // for
} //while
```

What happens if there was another set of if and else in the for loop? Would it just be ignored into

```
for (condition)
    if (condition)
    else 
if (condition)
else
```

Is there any other case I should watch for?

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets

Comment: Free advice: Don't tempt the devil... `else` is must be preceded by an `if` and together, they form a control block... a control block under a while/for loop is permitted

Comment: I understand there is a certain style, I am just curious where does a default for loop and while loop go up to instead of just reading that one single line when there are no brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`while (condition)` applies to the next **statement**. Often we use a **compound statement**, i.e., a line or more of code enclosed in curly braces:

```
while (condition)
{
/* code goes here */
}
```

but the statement doesn't have to be a compound statement:

```
while (condition)
    std::cout << "I'm still in the condition.\n";
```

and sometimes the statement can be more complicated:

```
while (condition)
    if (some_other_condition)
        /* some code here */
    else
       /* some other code here */
```

and the statement can be a looping statement:

```
while (condition)
    while (another_condition)
        while (yet_another_condition)
            /* whew, we got here! */
```

Answer (score 3):

The point is that all loops might iterate over a control block, which might either be:

1. a single control block (e.g. a statement), or
2. multiple control blocks grouped to a single one by `{...}`.

In your case,

```
while (condition)
for (condition)
if (condition)
else
```

`if...else` form a single control block, and so does `for`; hence, this is unambigously identical to

```
while (condition) {
    for (condition) {
        if (condition) {
           ...
        } else {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In all your examples, there is not a even a subtle point of confusion. There's only one way to interpret any of these so that it can compile. Try it yourself: place curly braces ('{' & '}') in each code fragment and try to give it 2 different meanings. You won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are no specific nesting rules for loops and conditional expressions. You just have to keep in mind that if you don't use braces, the loop executes only one statement.

Generally it is a good idea to always use braces.

Answer (score 0):

The both iteration statements are defined like

```
while ( condition ) statement
                    ^^^^^^^^^
for ( for-init-statement conditionopt; expressionopt) statement
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

where *statement* is any statement including the compound statement or empty statement.

So for example in this construction

```
while (condition) //without brackets
if (condition) statement
else statement
```

the *statement* is the if-else statement

```
if (condition) statement
else statement
```

You could enclose it in braces making a compound statement containing a single if-else statement

```
while (condition) //without brackets
{
if (condition) statement
else statement
}
```

However the effect would be the same.

In this construction

```
while (condition)
for (condition)
if (condition) statement
else statement
```

the while loop has the for loop as its statement that in turn has if-else as its own statement. You could write for example

```
while (condition)
{
    for (condition)
    {
        if (condition) statement
        else statement
    }
}
```

however the both compound statements contain only a single statement. So these two constructions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ambiguity; let's look up the actual grammar (C++11 §A.5):

The `while` and `for` are under *iteration-statement*

> *iteration-statement:*
>      `while (`*condition*`)` *statement*
>      `do`
>   *statement* `while (` *expression*`)`
>      `for (` *for-init-statement* *condition<sub>opt</sub>*;
>   *expression<sub>opt</sub>*`)` *statement*

(each row is an alternative pattern that satisfies the term that precedes the colon in the first row; words in italic are references to other grammar rules; the <sub>opt</sub> marks optional terms)

`if` and `if`/`else` are under *selection-statement*:

> *selection-statement:*
>      `if (` *condition* `)` *statement*
>      `if (` *condition* `)`
>   *statement* `else` *statement* 
>      `switch (` *condition* `)` *statement*

Now, as you can see they all require *one, single, generic* "*statement*" to execute, with no explicit mention of the braces; *statement*, in turn, is defined as:

> *statement:*
>      *labeled-statement*
>      *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *expression-statement*
>      *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *compound-statement*
>      *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *selection-statement*
>      *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *iteration-statement*
>      *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *jump-statement*
>      *declaration-statement*     *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*
>   *try-block*

let's forget about *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>*; the point to take home is that a *statement* in turn can be any of the `while`/`for`/`if` above, plus some other stuff, including the *compound-statement*, i.e. the braces:

> *compound-statement:*
>      `{` *statement-seq<sub>opt</sub>* `}`
>   *statement-seq:*
>      *statement*
>      *statement-seq* *statement*

(which is a formal way to say that inside the braces you can put one or more *statement*s)

Now, with this knowledge we can disentangle your example by thinking mechanically like the parser does:

```
for (condition)
if (condition)
doA();
else
doB();
if (condition)
doC();
else
doD();
```

- the `for` after the stuff in the `()` wants a *statement*; let's try to parse what follows as such:

  - there's an `if`; `if` either wants just a *statement* of a *statement* followed by `else` and another statement; let's see:

    - `doA()` is an *expression-statement*
    - an `else` follows
    - `doB()` is an *expression-statement*

    thus the whole `if (condition) doA(); else doB();` is a statement, in particular a *selection-statement*

  ok, we have full *statement* to provide as loop body to the `for`, so the `for` statement is completed;
- then, we have an `if-else`, which is parsed as above

  - `doC()` is an *expression-statement*
  - an `else` follows
  - `doD()` is an *expression-statement*

Thus, the final "braced" interpretation is

```
for (condition) {
    if (condition) {
        doA();
    } else {
        doB();
    }
}
if (condition) {
    doC();
} else {
    doD();
}
```