# I was writing this code for a pizza delivery system. When run from the command prompt it displayed an error. How should I run it?

Tags: c, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, unistd.h

I am building this pizza program using command-line arguments and interface. It should return the ingredients from the arguments.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *delivery = "";
    int thick = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char ch;


    while(ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t") != EOF)
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'd' :
            delivery = optarg;
            break;

            case 't' :
            thick = 1;
            break;

            default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid option : %s", optarg);
            return 1;
        }

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if(thick)
        puts("thick crust");

    if(delivery[0])
        printf("To be delivered %s", delivery);

    puts("ingredients :");

    for(count = 0; count<argc; count++)
    {
        puts(argv[count]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When running this program using command prompt in windows as :

> program -d now -t

it was returning an error :

> invalid option: now

How should I run this program and why is this error showing?

Comment: why are you doing `argc -=`/`argv +=`? changing loop sentinels inside the loop is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I don't think it's inside the loop.

Comment: Off topic : always put bracket (`{..}`) for control statements [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets). And take care about your indentation => we can think `argc -= optind;` and other lines are in the loop because they are indented like `switch` statement which is in loop

Comment: ah yes. the indentation makes it look like it is. there's no `{}` on the while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made five mistakes (two important, three less so) and one of the important mistakes is masking the other.

```
while(ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t") != EOF)
```

Important mistake #1: The [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) of `=` is *lower* than `!=`, so this assigns the *result of the comparison* to `ch`, not the return value of `getopt` as you expected.  Less important mistake #1: `getopt` returns −1 when it reaches the end of the options.  `EOF` is not necessarily equal to −1.

You should have written

```
while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != -1)
```

Now, when invoked as you described, in the first iteration the value returned from `getopt` will be `'d'`, which is not equal to `EOF` (nor to −1), so the value assigned to `ch` will be the number 1 (also known as Control-A, or `U+0001 START OF HEADING`).  This number is not equal to either `'d'` or `'t'` (the C standard guarantees `0 < 'a' < 'b' < 'c' < 'd' < ... < 'z'`, so even if we don't assume ASCII, 1 could only ever be equal to `'a'`) so the `default` branch of the `switch` is taken, and we do this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Invalid option : %s", optarg);
return 1;
```

And here is important mistake 2: you should print *`ch`*, not `optarg`, when you get an invalid option.  `ch` is the option; `optarg` is the *argument* to the option, if any.  If you had printed `ch` you would have realized that the value in `ch` was not what you expected it to be.

The other less important mistakes are

```
char ch;
```

This should be `int ch;`  Like in a `getchar` loop, the value returned from `getopt` when it reaches the end of the arguments is outside the range of `char`.

```
fprintf(stderr, "Invalid option : %s", optarg);
printf("To be delivered %s", delivery);
```

Both of these need a `\n` at the end of the string to be printed.

In the original form of your question, your code was badly indented, but I suspect that was because you used 4 spaces for a single level of indentation and an 8-space-wide hard TAB for a second level; it is a long-standing bug in the Stack Overflow interface that this kind of code gets mangled when pasted into a question.  So it's not your fault.  (You should indent with spaces only, though.)  The more serious style problem with your code is that some of your single-statement loops have curly braces around them and some of them don't.  Whether or not one should put curly braces around single-statement blocks in C is one of the oldest [holy wars](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HolyWar); I personally think both sides are wrong, but never mind that; the important thing you should learn is, pick one style or the other and *stick to it consistently throughout your code*.