# Maximize Window and restore to normal in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I want to Maximize window in WPF and I use below lines:

```
private void mnu_maximize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (main.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
        main.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
    main.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;

}
```

But the problem is when i click again for restore window to normal state it's not working and it's Stuck in Maximized state.
So How Can i fix this?

Comment: Be conscious, otherwise never underestimate an "if" which has no "else"

Comment: Look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an else part :

```
if (main.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
    main.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
else
    main.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

Updates:

In the given code, the conditional statement(`if`) is doing nothing, in all case the `main.WindowState` will be set to `Maximized`. That's why I told you to introduce an else there.

Comment: @komeilshahmoradi : In the given code, the conditional statement(`if`) is doing nothing, in all case  the `main.WindowState` will be set to `Maximized`. That's why i told you to introduce a else there.