# If else doing weird

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to make is to when i fill in the text box 1 that it will pop up kwa1 and when i put in 4 in the text box that it will popup kwa1 kwa2 kwa3 kwa4 but i cant get it to work please help me

```
function kwadraat(){

        var kwa1 = "het kwadraat van 1 = 1\n"
        var kwa2 = "het kwadraat van 2 = 4\n"
        var kwa3 = "het kwadraat van 3 = 9\n"
        var kwa4 = "het kwadraat van 4 = 16\n"
        var kwa5 = "het kwadraat van 5 = 25\n"
        var kwa6 = "het kwadraat van 6 = 36\n"
        var kwa7 = "het kwadraat van 7 = 49\n"
        var kwa8 = "het kwadraat van 8 = 64\n"
        var kwa9 = "het kwadraat van 9 = 81\n"
        var kwa10 = "het kwadraat van 10 = 100\n"
        var kwa11 = "het kwadraat van 11 = 121\n"
        var kwa12 = "het kwadraat van 12 = 144\n"
        var kwa13 = "het kwadraat van 13 = 169\n"
        var kwa14 = "het kwadraat van 14 = 196\n"
        var kwa15 = "het kwadraat van 15 = 225\n"
        var kwa16 = "het kwadraat van 16 = 256\n"
        var kwa17 = "het kwadraat van 17 = 289\n"
        var kwa18 = "het kwadraat van 18 = 324\n"
        var kwa19 = "het kwadraat van 19 = 361\n"
        var kwa20 = "het kwadraat van 20 = 400\n"

        if (document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value > "20");{
            alert("no solution")
        } 
        if (document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value === 1);{
            alert(kwa1);
        }
        if (document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value === 2);{
            alert(kwa1 + kwa2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to remove semicolon

Comment: And you want if also enter 7 alert `kwa1+kwa2+...kwa7` ?

Comment: (...).value > "20" technically not a bug, but is a bit questionable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For first remove semicolons after the `if ()`. `.value` returns `string`,so parse the value to `int` with [**parseInt()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). And last, your `if` statements will work correctly,because the value can hold only one value, but with your logic it is good to use `if-else-if`

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value) > 20){
            alert("no solution")
} 
else if (parseInt(document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value) === 1){
            alert(kwa1);
}
else if (parseInt(document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value) === 2){
            alert(kwa1 + kwa2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value` is a string, so it can not be `===` to 1, since it compares also the type. use [parseInt(number)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to **convert** it to **integer**.
- **Remove the `;`** from after the declarations; they are ruining your functions (and generaly not needed in js).
- If you use `document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value` three times, save it as a **short variable**.
- `if` conditions with one command inside can **ignore braces**.

---

That should result in:

```
value = parseInt(document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value)

if (value > 20)
    alert("no solution")
else if (value == 1)
    alert(kwa1)
else if (value == 2)
    alert(kwa1 + kwa2)
```

Comment: _if conditions with one command inside can ignore braces._ Yes, but IMHO [is bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets).

Comment: also although semi-colons aren't required after alerts, they make things cleaner IMO.

Comment: @abc123 they are not required *at all*.

Comment: @UrielEli IMO means in my opinion, feel free to have your own opinion.  I also stated...cleaner and aren't required.  I suppose you read after alerts and thought i meant only there, but instead I meant in your code.  I see now you didn't use them at all which is completely fine.  However, IMO it leads to [bad practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: @UrielEli Whitespace is also not required. It doesn't mean it's a good idea not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

### Notes:

This pulls the value into a variable which is parsed to an Int, this allows comparison with other ints.  Using a variable rather than pulling from the DOM repeatedly will give better performance.  The variable is also checked against NaN incase someone didn't enter a integer.

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      kwadraat();
    }, false);
}

function kwadraat(){
        var kwa1 = "het kwadraat van 1 = 1\n";
        var kwa2 = "het kwadraat van 2 = 4\n";
        var kwa3 = "het kwadraat van 3 = 9\n";
        var kwa4 = "het kwadraat van 4 = 16\n";
        var kwa5 = "het kwadraat van 5 = 25\n";
        var kwa6 = "het kwadraat van 6 = 36\n";
        var kwa7 = "het kwadraat van 7 = 49\n";
        var kwa8 = "het kwadraat van 8 = 64\n";
        var kwa9 = "het kwadraat van 9 = 81\n";
        var kwa10 = "het kwadraat van 10 = 100\n";
        var kwa11 = "het kwadraat van 11 = 121\n";
        var kwa12 = "het kwadraat van 12 = 144\n";
        var kwa13 = "het kwadraat van 13 = 169\n";
        var kwa14 = "het kwadraat van 14 = 196\n";
        var kwa15 = "het kwadraat van 15 = 225\n";
        var kwa16 = "het kwadraat van 16 = 256\n";
        var kwa17 = "het kwadraat van 17 = 289\n";
        var kwa18 = "het kwadraat van 18 = 324\n";
        var kwa19 = "het kwadraat van 19 = 361\n";
        var kwa20 = "het kwadraat van 20 = 400\n";
        
        var kwadraatboxValue = parseInt(document.getElementById("kwadraatbox").value);
        if(kwadraatboxValue === NaN) {
          alert('not a valid int');
        }
        else if (kwadraatboxValue > 20){
            alert("no solution");
        } 
        else if (kwadraatboxValue === 1){
            alert(kwa1);
        }
        else if (kwadraatboxValue === 2){
            alert(kwa1 + kwa2);
        }
    }
```

```html
<form>
  <label for='kwadraatbox'>
    <input type='text' id='kwadraatbox'/>
  </label>
  <input type='button' id='submit' value='submit'/>
  </form>
```