# Why use : instead of { in if statements

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

Why do people use

```
if(condition) :
    /*do something*/
else:
    /*do something else*/
endif;
```

instead of

```
if(condition) 
{
    /*do something*/
} 
else
{
    /*do something else*/
}
```

Is one better than the other in any way? What should i get use to too?

Comment: There is no better or worse, just different. A question of personal style. Some people find that the first version is easier to read when PHP is used embedded inside HTML. That's all. But it is kind of exotic, usually the second form is preferred and considered standard.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets

Comment: i think now, it just one of style of coding, some developers think : provide more readable code and another thinks  {} is more readable.

Comment: The version with : works very good (as in readable) when used directly in HTML.

Comment: it's more readable when dealing with PHP direct injection with HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This falls in the category of coding style. Some people like to use brackets some like to use the ":end..." notation. The advantage to the latter is more towards using PHP conditionals and loops where there is output to HTML. For example,

```
//Pure PHP with brackets
<?php
if ($condition) {
   echo "output";
}?>

//PHP and HTML with brackets
<?php
if ($condition) {?>
   output
<?php } ?>

//PHP and HTML with ":end..." notation
<?php if ($condition):?>
   output
<?php :endif ?>
```

Some people prefer the last as the ":endif" gives a clue what opening construct to look for when matching control structures. The bracket could match any other bracket but an ":endif" can only match and "if" construct. You can use either it is up to your style.