# Add Menu to Unity Roguelike Example

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

I play a little bit with the 2D Roguelike Asset from Unity.
I added an own scene for a main menu. Now if I start the game to this menu the game starts at day 1 and then go further to day 3 and skips day 2. I am not sure what causes this problem. I think it has something to do with the

```c#
    static private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
        instance.level++;
        instance.InitGame();
    }
```

is ther some workaround for this? I thought about reloading the game in another way, but I have no good idea for it.
Thanks in advance!

Best regards

EDIT:
GameManager:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

namespace Completed
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;       //Allows us to use Lists. 
    using UnityEngine.UI;       

        //Allows us to use UI.

    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float levelStartDelay = 2f;                      //Time to wait before starting level, in seconds.
        public float turnDelay = 0.1f;                          //Delay between each Player turn.
        public int playerFoodPoints = 100;                      //Starting value for Player food points.
        public int playerXP = 0;
        public int playerLvl = 1;
        public int wallDamage = 1;
        public static GameManager instance = null;              //Static instance of GameManager which allows it to be accessed by any other script.
        [HideInInspector] public bool playersTurn = true;       //Boolean to check if it's players turn, hidden in inspector but public.


        private Text levelText;                                 //Text to display current level number.
        private GameObject levelImage;                          //Image to block out level as levels are being set up, background for levelText.
        private BoardManager boardScript;                       //Store a reference to our BoardManager which will set up the level.
        private int level = 0;                                  //Current level number, expressed in game as "Day 1".
        public List<Enemy> enemies;                         //List of all Enemy units, used to issue them move commands.
        private bool enemiesMoving;                             //Boolean to check if enemies are moving.
        private bool doingSetup = true;                         //Boolean to check if we're setting up board, prevent Player from moving during setup.



        //Awake is always called before any Start functions
        void Awake()
        {
            level = 0;
            //Check if instance already exists
            if (instance == null)

                //if not, set instance to this
                instance = this;

            //If instance already exists and it's not this:
            else if (instance != this)

                //Then destroy this. This enforces our singleton pattern, meaning there can only ever be one instance of a GameManager.
                Destroy(gameObject);    

            //Sets this to not be destroyed when reloading scene
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

            //Assign enemies to a new List of Enemy objects.
            enemies = new List<Enemy>();

            //Get a component reference to the attached BoardManager script
            boardScript = GetComponent<BoardManager>();

             //Call the InitGame function to initialize the first level 
            InitGame();
        }

        //this is called only once, and the paramter tell it to be called only after the scene was loaded
        //(otherwise, our Scene Load callback would be called the very first load, and we don't want that)
        [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.AfterSceneLoad)]
        static public void CallbackInitialization()
        {
            //register the callback to be called everytime the scene is loaded
            SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        }

        //This is called each time a scene is loaded.
        static private void OnSceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
        {
            instance.level++;
            instance.InitGame();
            Debug.Log(instance.level);
        }


        //Initializes the game for each level.
        void InitGame()
        {
            //While doingSetup is true the player can't move, prevent player from moving while title card is up.
            doingSetup = true;

            //Get a reference to our image LevelImage by finding it by name.
            levelImage = GameObject.Find("LevelImage");

            //Get a reference to our text LevelText's text component by finding it by name and calling GetComponent.
            levelText = GameObject.Find("LevelText").GetComponent<Text>();

            //Set the text of levelText to the string "Day" and append the current level number.
            levelText.text = "Floor " + level;

            //Set levelImage to active blocking player's view of the game board during setup.
            levelImage.SetActive(true);

            //Call the HideLevelImage function with a delay in seconds of levelStartDelay.
            Invoke("HideLevelImage", levelStartDelay);

            //Clear any Enemy objects in our List to prepare for next level.
            enemies.Clear();

            //Call the SetupScene function of the BoardManager script, pass it current level number.
            boardScript.SetupScene(level);
        }


        //Hides black image used between levels
        void HideLevelImage()
        {
            //Disable the levelImage gameObject.
            levelImage.SetActive(false);

            //Set doingSetup to false allowing player to move again.
            doingSetup = false;
        }

        //Update is called every frame.
        void Update()
        {
            //Check that playersTurn or enemiesMoving or doingSetup are not currently true.
            if(playersTurn || enemiesMoving || doingSetup)

                //If any of these are true, return and do not start MoveEnemies.
                return;

            //Start moving enemies.
            StartCoroutine (MoveEnemies ());
        }

        //Call this to add the passed in Enemy to the List of Enemy objects.
        public void AddEnemyToList(Enemy script)
        {
            //Add Enemy to List enemies.
            enemies.Add(script);
        }

        public void RemoveEnemyFromList(Enemy script)
        {
            //Add Enemy to List enemies.
            enemies.Remove(script);
        }


        //GameOver is called when the player reaches 0 food points
        public void GameOver()
        {
            //Set levelText to display number of levels passed and game over message
            levelText.text = "After " + level + " days, you starved.";

            //Enable black background image gameObject.
            levelImage.SetActive(true);

            //Disable this GameManager.
            enabled = false;
        }

        //Coroutine to move enemies in sequence.
        IEnumerator MoveEnemies()
        {
            //While enemiesMoving is true player is unable to move.
            enemiesMoving = true;

            //Wait for turnDelay seconds, defaults to .1 (100 ms).
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);

            //If there are no enemies spawned (IE in first level):
            if (enemies.Count == 0) 
            {
                //Wait for turnDelay seconds between moves, replaces delay caused by enemies moving when there are none.
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnDelay);
            }

            //Loop through List of Enemy objects.
            for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Count; i++)
            {
                //Call the MoveEnemy function of Enemy at index i in the enemies List.
                enemies[i].MoveEnemy ();

                //Wait for Enemy's moveTime before moving next Enemy, 
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(enemies[i].moveTime);
            }

            //Enemies are done moving, set enemiesMoving to false.
            enemiesMoving = false;
            //Once Enemies are done moving, set playersTurn to true so player can move.
            playersTurn = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Player:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;   //Allows us to use UI.
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

namespace Completed
{
    //Player inherits from MovingObject, our base class for objects that can move, Enemy also inherits from this.
    public class Player : MovingObject
    {
        public float restartLevelDelay = 1f;        //Delay time in seconds to restart level.
        public int pointsPerFood = 10;              //Number of points to add to player food points when picking up a food object.
        public int pointsPerSoda = 20;              //Number of points to add to player food points when picking up a soda object.
        public int wallDamage = 1;                  //How much damage a player does to a wall when chopping it.
        public int enemyDamage = 1;
        public int xp = 0;
        public int lvl = 1;
        public Text foodText;                       //UI Text to display current player food total.
        public Text xpText;
        public Text lvlText;
        public Text attText;
        public AudioClip moveSound1;                //1 of 2 Audio clips to play when player moves.
        public AudioClip moveSound2;                //2 of 2 Audio clips to play when player moves.
        public AudioClip eatSound1;                 //1 of 2 Audio clips to play when player collects a food object.
        public AudioClip eatSound2;                 //2 of 2 Audio clips to play when player collects a food object.
        public AudioClip drinkSound1;               //1 of 2 Audio clips to play when player collects a soda object.
        public AudioClip drinkSound2;               //2 of 2 Audio clips to play when player collects a soda object.
        public AudioClip gameOverSound;             //Audio clip to play when player dies.

        public Portrait portrait;

        private Animator animator;                  //Used to store a reference to the Player's animator component.
        public int food;                           //Used to store player food points total during level.
#if UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_WP8 || UNITY_IPHONE
        private Vector2 touchOrigin = -Vector2.one; //Used to store location of screen touch origin for mobile controls.
#endif


        //Start overrides the Start function of MovingObject
        protected override void Start ()
        {
            //Get a component reference to the Player's animator component
            animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

            //Get the current food point total stored in GameManager.instance between levels.
            food = GameManager.instance.playerFoodPoints;
            xp = GameManager.instance.playerXP;
            lvl = GameManager.instance.playerLvl;
            wallDamage = GameManager.instance.wallDamage;

            //Update portrait
            if(food < 110)
                portrait.Normal();
            if(food >= 110)
                portrait.Fat();

            //Set the foodText to reflect the current player food total.
            foodText.text = "Food: " + food;
            xpText.text = "XP: " + xp;
            lvlText.text = "Lvl: " + lvl;
            attText.text = ": " + wallDamage;
            //Call the Start function of the MovingObject base class.
            base.Start ();
        }


        //This function is called when the behaviour becomes disabled or inactive.
        private void OnDisable ()
        {
            //When Player object is disabled, store the current local food total in the GameManager so it can be re-loaded in next level.
            GameManager.instance.playerFoodPoints = food;
            GameManager.instance.playerXP = xp;
            GameManager.instance.playerLvl = lvl;
            GameManager.instance.wallDamage = wallDamage;
        }


        private void Update ()
        {
            //If it's not the player's turn, exit the function.
            if(!GameManager.instance.playersTurn) return;

            int horizontal = 0;     //Used to store the horizontal move direction.
            int vertical = 0;       //Used to store the vertical move direction.

            //Check if we are running either in the Unity editor or in a standalone build.
#if UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_WEBPLAYER

            //Get input from the input manager, round it to an integer and store in horizontal to set x axis move direction
            horizontal = (int) (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal"));

            //Get input from the input manager, round it to an integer and store in vertical to set y axis move direction
            vertical = (int) (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical"));

            //Check if moving horizontally, if so set vertical to zero.
            if(horizontal != 0)
            {
                vertical = 0;
            }
            //Check if we are running on iOS, Android, Windows Phone 8 or Unity iPhone
#elif UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_WP8 || UNITY_IPHONE

            //Check if Input has registered more than zero touches
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                //Store the first touch detected.
                Touch myTouch = Input.touches[0];

                //Check if the phase of that touch equals Began
                if (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    //If so, set touchOrigin to the position of that touch
                    touchOrigin = myTouch.position;
                }

                //If the touch phase is not Began, and instead is equal to Ended and the x of touchOrigin is greater or equal to zero:
                else if (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended && touchOrigin.x >= 0)
                {
                    //Set touchEnd to equal the position of this touch
                    Vector2 touchEnd = myTouch.position;

                    //Calculate the difference between the beginning and end of the touch on the x axis.
                    float x = touchEnd.x - touchOrigin.x;

                    //Calculate the difference between the beginning and end of the touch on the y axis.
                    float y = touchEnd.y - touchOrigin.y;

                    //Set touchOrigin.x to -1 so that our else if statement will evaluate false and not repeat immediately.
                    touchOrigin.x = -1;

                    //Check if the difference along the x axis is greater than the difference along the y axis.
                    if (Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Abs(y))
                        //If x is greater than zero, set horizontal to 1, otherwise set it to -1
                        horizontal = x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                    else
                        //If y is greater than zero, set horizontal to 1, otherwise set it to -1
                        vertical = y > 0 ? 1 : -1;
                }
            }

#endif //End of mobile platform dependendent compilation section started above with #elif
            //Check if we have a non-zero value for horizontal or vertical
            if(horizontal != 0 || vertical != 0)
            {
                //Call AttemptMove passing in the generic parameter Wall, since that is what Player may interact with if they encounter one (by attacking it)
                //Pass in horizontal and vertical as parameters to specify the direction to move Player in.
                AttemptMove<Wall> (horizontal, vertical);
            }
        }

        //AttemptMove overrides the AttemptMove function in the base class MovingObject
        //AttemptMove takes a generic parameter T which for Player will be of the type Wall, it also takes integers for x and y direction to move in.
        protected override void AttemptMove <T> (int xDir, int yDir)
        {
            //Every time player moves, subtract from food points total.
            food--;

            //Update portrait
            if(food < 110)
                portrait.Normal();
            if(food >= 110)
                portrait.Fat();

            //Update food text display to reflect current score.
            foodText.text = "Food: " + food;
            xpText.text = "XP: " + xp;
            lvlText.text = "Lvl: " + lvl;
            attText.text = ": " + wallDamage;

            //Call the AttemptMove method of the base class, passing in the component T (in this case Wall) and x and y direction to move.
            base.AttemptMove <T> (xDir, yDir);

            //Hit allows us to reference the result of the Linecast done in Move.
            RaycastHit2D hit;

            //If Move returns true, meaning Player was able to move into an empty space.
            if (Move (xDir, yDir, out hit)) 
            {
                //Call RandomizeSfx of SoundManager to play the move sound, passing in two audio clips to choose from.
                SoundManager.instance.RandomizeSfx (moveSound1, moveSound2);
            }

            //Since the player has moved and lost food points, check if the game has ended.
            CheckIfGameOver ();

            //Set the playersTurn boolean of GameManager to false now that players turn is over.
            GameManager.instance.playersTurn = false;
        }


        //OnCantMove overrides the abstract function OnCantMove in MovingObject.
        //It takes a generic parameter T which in the case of Player is a Wall which the player can attack and destroy.
        protected override void OnCantMove <T> (T component)
        {

            //Set hitWall to equal the component passed in as a parameter.
            Wall hitWall = component as Wall;

            //Call the DamageWall function of the Wall we are hitting.
            hitWall.DamageWall (wallDamage);


            //Set the attack trigger of the player's animation controller in order to play the player's attack animation.
            animator.SetTrigger ("playerChop");
        }


        //OnTriggerEnter2D is sent when another object enters a trigger collider attached to this object (2D physics only).
        private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other)
        {
            //Check if the tag of the trigger collided with is Exit.
            if(other.tag == "Exit")
            {
                //Invoke the Restart function to start the next level with a delay of restartLevelDelay (default 1 second).
                Invoke ("Restart", restartLevelDelay);

                //Disable the player object since level is over.
                enabled = false;
            }

            //Check if the tag of the trigger collided with is Food.
            else if(other.tag == "Food")
            {   
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Food", 1);
                //Add pointsPerFood to the players current food total.
                food += pointsPerFood;

                //Update foodText to represent current total and notify player that they gained points
                foodText.text = "+" + pointsPerFood + " Food: " + food;

                //Call the RandomizeSfx function of SoundManager and pass in two eating sounds to choose between to play the eating sound effect.
                SoundManager.instance.RandomizeSfx (eatSound1, eatSound2);

                //Disable the food object the player collided with.
                other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            }

            //Check if the tag of the trigger collided with is Soda.
            else if(other.tag == "Soda")
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Soda", 1);
                //Add pointsPerSoda to players food points total
                food += pointsPerSoda;

                //Update foodText to represent current total and notify player that they gained points
                foodText.text = "+" + pointsPerSoda + " Food: " + food;

                //Call the RandomizeSfx function of SoundManager and pass in two drinking sounds to choose between to play the drinking sound effect.
                SoundManager.instance.RandomizeSfx (drinkSound1, drinkSound2);

                //Disable the soda object the player collided with.
                other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            }
        }


        //Restart reloads the scene when called.
        private void Restart ()
        {
            //Load the last scene loaded, in this case Main, the only scene in the game. And we load it in "Single" mode so it replace the existing one
            //and not load all the scene object in the current scene.
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, LoadSceneMode.Single);
        }


        //LoseFood is called when an enemy attacks the player.
        //It takes a parameter loss which specifies how many points to lose.
        public void LoseFood (int loss)
        {
            //Set the trigger for the player animator to transition to the playerHit animation.
            animator.SetTrigger ("playerHit");

            //Subtract lost food points from the players total.
            food -= loss;

            //Update the food display with the new total.
            foodText.text = "-"+ loss + " Food: " + food;

            //Check to see if game has ended.
            CheckIfGameOver ();
        }


        //CheckIfGameOver checks if the player is out of food points and if so, ends the game.
        private void CheckIfGameOver ()
        {
            //Check if food point total is less than or equal to zero.
            if (food <= 0) 
            {
                //Call the PlaySingle function of SoundManager and pass it the gameOverSound as the audio clip to play.
                SoundManager.instance.PlaySingle (gameOverSound);

                //Stop the background music.
                SoundManager.instance.musicSource.Stop();

                //Call the GameOver function of GameManager.
                GameManager.instance.GameOver ();
            }
        }

        public void getXP(){
            xp += 5;
            xpText.text = "XP: " + xp;
            Debug.Log(xp);
            if(xp == 10)
                LevelUp();
        }

        private void LevelUp(){
            lvl += 1;
            lvlText.text ="UP! Lvl: " + lvl;
            wallDamage += 1;
            attText.text = "+1 : " + wallDamage;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Player Script the Reload() function reloads the scene.

Comment: Could you provide the code of the object that holds the information of which day it is? And the code that changes the day.

Comment: Added the script from Player and GameManager I think that are the only 2 who handels the day and scene loading

Comment: Not related to your question but if i were you i would start by fragmenting your code into different scripts and give them propper names and use namespaces. And i would make the singleton only hold data and  pull it out whenever u start a scene.

Comment: Are you creating more then one instance of game manager since you are using instance.level++; and instance is static; ?you should use level++ i think.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `instance.level++;` rather use `level++;` instead.
  Since instance is static.
- Your `singleton` is not destroying the script it is destroying the `gameObject` and runs until it calls `init()` which increases level.
- `GameManager instance = null;` becomes `GameManager instance;`
- Adjust your `if` statements in the future especially if you are new to c#.
  more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125078/8165010)
- Regarding singleton:
  `else if (instance != this)` becomes `if (instance != this)`
  and `Destroy(gameObject)` becomes `Destroy(this);`

Comment: if I do so, I get "an object reference is required to access non-static member 'Completed.GameManager.level'"

Comment: you declare it though; private int level = 0;

Comment: your code is all over the place; i just noticed; public static GameManager instance = null; Remove the =null.

Comment: ok, then should I change it that it is only destroying the script and not the whole gameobject? I also forgot to mention that if I run only the game scene without starting it through the menu scene it all works well.

Comment: GameManager instance = null; Remove "= null" Do this first and tell me what happens.

Comment: without condoning or condemning i would like say; stop copy pasting stuff into your scripts which u do not understand. If you did write this yourself try adding better structure and comment a bit less and give functions and methods names that make sense so you do not need to comment that often.

Comment: I know thats why I am playing around with this free asset from the store and I wondered why it comes to this error, thats all, you can find this script as it is in the asset store.

Comment: @potu1304 Some of the code they provide is not even working, I am very surprised by this.