# Can't pass values between main() and a function (lists)

Tags: c, string, list, singly-linked-list

I'm "working" in a school project that needs to use linked lists with chars* and some other variables. The thing is:

I'm using a sub-function to open, read and store the data in a List but can't access to the string on it, I mean, can see other infos just dont that one...

```
void main()
{
    Palavra* P = lerPalavras();
    printf ("%s", P->c);               //Was just testing in this ...
}
```

The sub-funtion

```
Palavra* lerPalavras ()               //Just ignore what is going on here in the code, the problem is when I call it, within the function the output works just fine, but when I pass to main it's just not working at all. Thanks
{
    char linha [50];
    Palavra* P = NULL;
    Palavra* pv = NULL;
    FILE* ficheiro = fopen ("keywords.txt", "r");

    if(ficheiro == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Abertura do Ficheiro 'keywords.txt' Falhou!");
        return NULL;
    }   
    while (fgets (linha, sizeof (linha), 
    {
        if (linha [strlen(linha) - 1] != '\n')
            linha [strlen(linha)] = '\0';
        else
            linha [strlen(linha) - 1] = '\0';
        pv = CriaKW ();
        pv->c = linha;
        pv->tam = strlen (linha);
        P = insertKW (P, pv);
    }
    fclose (ficheiro);
    return (P);
}
```

The struct "Mensagem"

```
typedef struct KW
{
    char* c;
    struct KW* nseg;
    int ID;
    long int tam;
} Palavra;
```

The function "CriaKW"

```
Palavra* CriaKW ()                                          
{
    Palavra * pv = (Palavra*) malloc (sizeof (Palavra));
    return (pv);
}
```

The function "insertKW"

```
Palavra* insertKW (Palavra* P, Palavra* pv)
{
    pv->nseg = NULL;
    if (P == NULL)                      //Ver se a Lista está vazia
        return (pv);
    Palavra* p = P;                     //Variável Auxiliar para não perder a cabeça da Lista
    while (p->nseg != NULL)             //Ver se a "caixa" tem seguinte
        p = p->nseg;                    //Correr a Lista
    p->nseg = pv;
    return (P);
}
```

Comment: I suggest [always using curly braces for branching and looping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-brackets).

Comment: What do you mean by "not working at all"?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. Is the return value of `lerPalavras` not what you expected? If so, what is the definition of  `insertKW`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Diogo Dias The array linha is a local variable of the function. So this statement  pv->c = linha; results in undefined behavior after exiting the function. That is the pointer will have an invalid value.

Comment: Did add the functions, sorry about that. @Jose I mean when I try to use P->c in main and P->c in function that are diferent values (only function is correct)

Comment: Yea, that's what @VladfromMoscow is saying. The function gets a correct value but then passes the *address* of the value, not the value itself. After the function returns, it's memory is used for something else and that address no longer holds the value it returned.

Comment: oh thanks, any way to do that ? Should I convert char into char* than it should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `linha` is a local object of the function

```
Palavra* lerPalavras ()
{
    char linha [50];
    //...
```

and has the automatic storage duration, After exiting the function it will not be alive and can be either overwritten by other objects of the program or even inaccessible.

In any case the pointer `pv->c` of each node initialized this way

```
pv->c = linha;
```

will have an invalid value after exiting the function.

You should dynamically allocate memory pointed to by this pointer and copy the original string to the allocated memory.

For example

```
linha[ strcspn( linha, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
size_t n = strlen( linha );

pv->c = malloc( n + 1 );
strcpy( pv->c, linha );
pv->tam = n;
```

Also you need to remember to free the memory allocated for the string when a node of the list is deleted.

Take into account that it is better instead of the type `long int` to use the type `size_t` for data member `tam` because in general it is not necessary that the type `size_t` is equivalent to the type `long int` though the standard function `strlen` and other string functions use the type `size_t.`.

```
size_t tam;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems due to the line: `pv->c = linha;`

1. It's saving a pointer to a local variable in the structure that it's returning. That variable is destroyed when the function returns, so the pointer is no longer valid.
2. You're using the same `linha` variable for every line that you read. So even if the variable weren't destroyed, all the `Palavra` structures would have the last line of the file.

You need to make a copy of the line to save it. Change that line to:

```
pv->c = strdup(linha);
```

`strdup()` is a POSIX function, not standard C. If that's a restriction on your code, it should be simple for you to write it yourself using `malloc()` and `strcpy()`.

BTW, this line is not needed:

```
        linha [strlen(linha)] = '\0';
```

Since `strlen()` works by finding the position of the `\0` character, this is just setting that character to what it already has. Change the `if` that contains this to:

```
if (linha[strlen(linha)-1] == '\n') {
    linha[strlen(linha)-1] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, I'm new here but you all tried to help! Thanks a lot!

Did this code:
    pv->c = strdup(linha);

Comment: It would be better to remove this answer because it is actually a comment. Otherwise somebody can down-vote it.