# How do I write a proper else if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to write a method that finds the smallest out of three numbers. I think something is wrong with the "else if" statement in my code here. It keeps telling me that "variable d may not have been initialized." but I did initialize it. Maybe I wrote the "else if" statement wrong.

```
public class Solution {
    public static int min(int a, int b, int c) {
        int d;
        if ((a <= b) && (b <= c))
            d = a;
        else if ((a >= b) && (b >= c))
            d = c;

        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(min(1, 2, 3));
        System.out.println(min(-1, -2, -3));
        System.out.println(min(3, 5, 3));
        System.out.println(min(5, 5, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: `ind d;` *declares* it. It doesn't initialize it. It looks like you want to initialize it to `b`: `int d = b;`

Comment: if not `if` **AND** if not `else if` - what is `d` ?

Comment: I think you also forgot the `else` case

Comment: `return Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));`

Comment: Tip: [It's almost always better to use curly braces even if the statement is just one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125078/2431281). [Apple could have prevented a security mishap had they done so](https://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int d = a;
if (d > b) {
  d = b;
} 
if (d > c) {
  d = c;
}
return d;
```

The error happened because 
int d; declares it and not initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `int d` is assigned a value before the return statement. Your logic is also wrong and you have missed else statement in your code. You can try the code below:

```
  public static int min(int a, int b, int c) {

  int d ;
  if ((a <= b) && (a <= c))
      {
      d = a;
      }  
  else if ((a >= b) && (b <= c))
      {
      d = b;
      }
  else
      {
      d=c;
      }

  return d;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Either initialize `int d` with a value, and/or include an `else` statement to assign `d` encase the `return` statement throws a `null`. You should always plan for what happens when your `if` and `if else` statements are evaluated as `false`.

Answer (score -6):

Use int `d=0;`

to intilize d with NULL

Remember: When using elseif{} you must have to endup with else{}

```
if(condition){

}else if(condition){

}
else{
}
```

Comment: It's incredible how absolutely everything in this answer is wrong.