# My discord bot repeats the statement again and again, how to fix that?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

**I am trying to make a discord.js bot like invitemanager that will give the invites of a user in server. If I can get a alternative code that will be also fine, i surfed all over the internet but not found any source code of invite manager or something like that, please anyone resolve my problem. That invite manager bot sucks that's why i wanna make my own bot which will manage invites in my server. Currently i got this code but it just repeat over and over again and also the commandtrigger isn't working. The commands starts executing in whatever you typed. Please give a solution for that.

Thanks in advance**

````
const client = new Discord.Client();
let activenum = 0;

client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setStatus('available')
    client.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: 'ᴛʜᴇ ᴏꜰꜰɪᴄɪᴀʟ ʙᴄ',
            type: "STREAMING",
            url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-mTkE8YJEPU"
        }
    });
});

var prefix = "-"
var adminprefix = '-'


//bc


  client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === '-invite')
    var targetUser = null;
        var isAnotherUserLookup = false;
        if(message.mentions.members.first() != null)
        {
            targetUser = message.mentions.members.first();
            isAnotherUserLookup = true;
        }
        else
            targetUser = message.member;

        message.guild.fetchInvites()
        .then
        (invites =>
            {var targetUser = null;
        var isAnotherUserLookup = false;
        if(message.mentions.members.first() != null)
        {
            targetUser = message.mentions.members.first().user;
            console.log(targetUser.user);
            isAnotherUserLookup = true;
        }
        else
            targetUser = message.author;

        message.guild.fetchInvites()
        .then
        (invites =>
            {
                const userInvites = invites.array().filter(o => o.inviter.id === targetUser.id);
                var userInviteCount = 0;

                    if(isAnotherUserLookup)
                        message.channel.send(`User _${targetUser.username}_ has invited ${userInviteCount} user(s) to this server.`);

                    else
                        message.reply(`You have invited ${userInviteCount} user(s) to this server. Keep up the good work!`);
          return;
            }
        )
            }
        )
  });




client.login(process.env.token);```

https://glitch.com/~colossal-trumpet
````

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement doesn't have curly braces; Meaning that it will only be applied to the line after it.

This means that you don't actually have a command filter to determine when the bot sends the invite messsage. The bot will just send the invite message each time it recieves any message (including from itself!)

Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125066/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-an-if-statement-without-curly-braces).