# .net code readability and maintainability

Tags: c#, .net

There Currently is a local debate as to which code is more readability

We have one programmer who comes from a c background and when that programmer codes it looks like

```
string foo = "bar";

if (foo[foo.Length - 1] == 'r')
{

}
```

We have another programmer that doesn't like this methodology and would rather use

```
if (foo.EndsWith("r"))
{

}
```

which way of doing these types of operations is better?

Comment: Not to be looking for a needle in a haystack, but isn't "legible" the right word, instead of readable or readbly?

Comment: The first example shouldn't be used at all - even if it was more readable than the second example - since no null or length check is made on foo.

Comment: The second, wouldn't the first one crash if the string was empty?

Comment: @patrik, @SLC

You are correct it will crash with an empty string. This code is ment to illustrate programming styles and not to reflect production code

Answer (score 39, accepted):

EndsWidth is more readable to someone who has never seen C or C++, C#, or any other programming language.

Comment: True, but why would someone who's never seen C, C++, C#, Objective-C, Java, Perl, PHP, or any other C derivative be trying to decipher your code? And remember, anyone who's been coding in Python or VB these days will have seen one of these languages at some point.

Comment: +1 because this ain't C, and I even like C.

Comment: @Dinah, consider a person who's done Java but looking at some C#. A string's == is not the same between the two languages. "EndsWith" is less ambiguous.

Comment: @statenjason: fair enough. But I wonder if this fringe case is enough to merit a guideline. For the record, I agree that EndsWith() is more readable and intuitive. I disagree that it should be done for people who have "C or C++, C#, or any other programming language". Even more so because the OP stated that the conflict of opinion is with someone who comes from a C background. Mostly, I like Chris Marisic's above rationale.

Comment: @statenjason: This just shows how unclear that can be, since the example isn't even doing string comparison, it is doing character comparison.

Answer (score 12):

The second one is more [declarative in style](http://togaroga.com/2010/03/writing-better-code-its-imperative-that-you-are-declarative/) but I can't tell you objectively if it is more readable sine readability is very subjective.  I personally find the second one more readable myself but that is just my opinion.

Here is an excerpt from my article:

> Most C# developers are very familiar
>   with writing imperative code (even
>   though they may not know it by that
>   name). In this article, I will
>   introduce you to an alternative style
>   of programming called declarative
>   programming. Proper declarative code
>   is easier to read, understand, and
>   maintain.
>
> As professionals, we should be
>   striving to write better code each
>   day. If you cannot look at code you
>   wrote three months ago with a critical
>   eye and notice things that could be
>   better, then you have not improved and
>   are not challenging yourself. I
>   challenge you to write code that is
>   easier to read and understand by using
>   declarative code.

Comment: Nice blog post. The most common theme in the post: make your intent as clear as possible and declarative programming helps you do that.

Comment: @AndrewHare is the link to your blog still available? I cant access.

Comment: Would like to read the blog ... link above is 404!

Answer (score 9):

Number 2 is better to read and to mantain.
Example: Verify the last 2 characters ...

Option 1)

```
if (foo[foo.Length - 1] == 'r' && foo[foo.Length - 2] == 'a')
{

}
```

Option 2)

```
if (foo.EndsWith("ar"))
{

}
```

last 3? last 4?...

Comment: You would do this:
    if (foo.substring(foo.Length-2,2) == "ar")

Answer (score 8):

I come from a C/C++ background and I vote for Endswith!

Answer (score 7):

**Readability rules**, especially if it implies intent.

With the first example I must discover the intent - which is left for interpretation. If it appears to have a bug, how do I know that's not intentional?

The second example is telling me the intent. We want to find the end character. Armed with that knowledge I can proceed with evaluating the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I think the second way is better because it is more easy to read and because the first one duplicates logic of `EndsWith` method which is bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

I think the right answer would be the one that is actually correct.  `EndsWith` properly returns `false` for empty string input whereas the other test will throw an exception trying to index with -1.

Answer (score 3):

Not only is EndWith more readable, but also more 'correct'. 
As a rule, if there is a framework method provided to do the job ... use it.

What if foo == string.Empty?

Comment: trying to find an answer along these lines - if not I was going to write it myself. here it is all the way at the bottom!

Answer (score 2):

IMO, the intent of the original author is clearer in the second example. In the first, the reader must evaluate what the author is trying to accomplish by pulling the last index. It is not difficult, but requires more effort on the part of the reader.

Answer (score 2):

EndsWith is probably safer.  But the indexer is probably faster.

Endswith probably checks to see if the input string is empty.  They will probably both throw null reference exceptions.  And the indexer will fail is the length is 0.

**As for readability,** they both say the same thing to me, but I have been programming for a while.  The `.EndsWith(...)` is probably faster to grasp without considering context.

Comment: Thanks down voter.  How about a comment.  I was making the point that the code isn't really the same (and I was revising my statement as you down voted.)

Answer (score 2):

Both approaches are valid, but the endswith method is easier to read in my opinion. It also does away with the potential to make typing mistakes etc with the more complicated form..

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much does the same thing. However, it gets more complicated with more than one character in the endswith argument. However, the first example is slightly faster as it uses no actual functions and thus requires no stack. You might want to define a macro which can be used to simply make everything uniform.

Comment: Are you certain #1 is faster? I would expect the C# compiler to do automatic [inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) in #2.

Comment: The question is about maintainability.  Choosing one of these "styles" for performance is a micro-optimization that will never pay off as soon as a programmer spends an extra few seconds trying to understand what it does.

Comment: @Jørn Schou-Rode: The compiler won't inline anything.  The JITer may, but it depends on many things including how much code is behind the method call.

Comment: @Matthew: Indeed, but that really does not change my point :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the main criteria should be which of these most clearly says what the developer wants to do.  What does each sample actually *say*?

1)Access the character at position one less than the length, and check if it equals the character 'r'

2)Check if it ends with the string "r"

I think that makes it clear which is the more maintainable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless and until it does not affect the program performance, no problem you can use either way. But adding code comments is very important for conveying what is being accomplished.

Comment: The first one needs a comment and the second one does not.

Answer (score 0):

"Code is written to be read by humans and incidently run by computers" SICP

`EndsWith` FTW!!

Answer (score 0):

From an error handling standpoint, EndsWith.

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer the second (`EndsWith`) version. It's clear enough for even my manager to understand!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to write code that is easily readable. If you used the first one, developers that are debugging your code may say, "What is this dev trying to do?" You need to utilize methods that are easily explained. If a method is too complicated to figure out, retract several methods out of it.

I would definitely say the second one, **legibility** and **simplicity** are key!

Also, if the "if" statement has one line, *DONT BOTHER USING BRACES, USE A SINGLE INDENTION*

Comment: `if the "if" statement has one line, DONT BOTHER USING BRACES, USE A SINGLE INDENTION` - this is really arbitrary advice you didn't even justify. You don't know when the "if" block will grow into more lines. If it does on another branch, you can get a merge conflict.  Skipping braces can also lead to bugs - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces for a bunch of examples. Coding style is a matter of taste, but we shouldn't present our preferences as a dogma, especially without backing them up with any rationale.

Comment: yeah....this was almost 4 years ago. I've learned so much since then. thanks though!

Comment: I know, it can be a long time in programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in classic C, the only difference between a "string" and an array of characters is that terminating null character '\0', so we had to more actively treat them accordingly and to make sure that we did not run off the end of the array. So the first block of code bases its thought process on the concept of an array of characters.

The second block of code bases the thought process on how you handle a string more abstractly and with less regard to its implementation under the covers.

So in a nutshell, if you are talking about processing characters as the main idea behind your project, go with the first piece.  If you are talking about preparing a string for something greater and that does not necessarily need to focus on the mechanics of the ways that strings are built -- or you just want to keep it simple -- go with the second style.

Some of this might summarize others' contributions at this point, but more analogously put, are you playing "Bingo();" or are you "playing a game with a two-dimensional array of random integers, etc.?"

Hopefully this helps.

Jim