# Hide curly braces in C#

Tags: c#, python, coding-style

After getting back into Python, I'm starting to notice and be annoyed more and more by my C# coding style requiring braces everywhere

```
 if (...)
 {
     return ...;
 }
 else
 {
     return ...;
 }
```

preferring the (subjective) much cleaner looking python counter-part

```
if ...:
    return ...
else
    return ...
```

is there any way I can go about hiding these braces (as they do take up about 30% of my coding screen on average and just look ugly!)

Comment: What program are you using to edit your code?

Comment: Just omit them. For single statements you don't need them in C#.

Comment: I think this is an unfortunate consequence of using C#. You could try same-line curly braces which looks a lot better but that's not the community standard for C# :(

Comment: +1 yeah, awesome! didn't know i could do it with the else and else if as well, thx

Comment: One possibility is to set the editor settings to give { } a very bright color (or dark if you're using a dark background)

Comment: @sinelaw thought about that but then i'd have *ALOT* more white spaces and it would make the code even less readable

Comment: Just be careful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces

Comment: how's that going to reduce the fact that they take 30% of the coding screen? they'll still take 30% of the screen and be an eye sore. in fact 30% of a bigger screen's gonna be a BIGGER eye sore! i should downvote ur comment hehe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, but if you're coding in C# and doing more than just simple single-expression blocks, you're going to have to suck it up.  Python's "indent-denotes-scope" grammar may be nice, but it's Python, not C#.

Answer (score 5):

You could switch to:

```
 if (...) {
     return ...;
 } else {
     return ...;
 }
```

to gain some screen.

I think it's a bad idea to pretend that C# works like Python though.

Comment: alas the screen space is only half the problem, if i could hide them altogether it would look better. i actually switched to having the { on one line to improve readability.

Comment: @Joe I don't think "it would look better" is enough reason to do this. If you're going to be using C# a lot you'll do a lot better to get used to the syntax.

Comment: oh believe me i'm used to the syntax, but it's just that i had more or less a wow moment as i was working on my pet project in python on the weekend and when i came into work this morning i couldn't help but notice all the braces that i'd had written over the years... and thought wouldn't it be coooool if i could hide it

Answer (score 2):

```
if (condition) {
    statement1
    statement2; }
else {
    statement3;
    statemen4; }
```

much uglier in my opinion :(

Comment: ewwww.. that's horrible.. hehe

Comment: If only it was possible to choose same foreground color for the braces as the editor background color in Visual Studio it could be excellent idea .

Answer (score 1):

If you need .NET but like Python syntax, you might like to check [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/).

Comment: +1 i've had a read, whilst boo might not meet my simplistic needs of hiding curly braces, it might eventually satisfy my desire of writing like python in .net... but isn't that what IronPython does? ..googling... apparently there's some differences there too

Answer (score 1):

If you're feeling really evil:

```
if (iAmEvil)                                                                                                             {
    LookMa();
    NoBraces();
    OrSemiColonsForThatMatter()                                                                                         ;}
else {
    IfYouDontGetIt();
    ScrollRight();
}
```

Of course, it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: i was wondering how this was possible, copy paste into linqpad and saw the 'hidden' text. Not sure if this is appropriate as an answer, tempted to downvote (from a noise point of view).

Comment: that sounded harsher than intended, it was funny :) not downvoting... but still not sure if it should be an answer... O_O

Comment: Well, http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down states that downvotes are for "an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect". My 'solution' *does* get the job done (hides braces as well as semicolons), and certainly took a bit of effort on my part to write out all those spaces. By those standards I'm pretty sure I've made a perfectly valid answer. If you want to downvote, then go ahead - the humor was worth the price :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can omit the braces in C#, so long as the `if` and `else` "blocks" are just single statements:

```
// perfectly legal
if (...)
    return ...
else
    return ...
```

If you need multi-line `if` and `else` blocks then you're stuck with braces.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need the brackets if you have only one statement. For example, the following is working:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       if (i == 9)
           break;
   ```

(even though that code does not make any sense)

1. You can change the settings in Visual C# for formatting C# code as Skilldrick says, to make the code shorter:

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> formatting (or something similar, I only have the german version of visual studio).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

C/C++/Java/C# folks have an ages old racist kind of family feud with the Cobol/BASIC/Python clan. It's a real either/or thing... No best-of-the-both-world's, having-cakes-and-eating-them-too fun allowed :)

Answer (score -1):

For single statements you do not need the curly braces. For times you need them you might be OK with placing the braces like:

```
if(expr) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out [scribes](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/download.html), its a really nice editor that is customizable to a large extent, and I'm quite sure that you can do what you needed with it.

Comment: scribes is not even for windows, and how is it going to do what i need with it?