# Combining multiple if statements

Tags: c#, if-statement, visibility, multiple-instances

I have the following piece of code which I am using to set a series of labels to invisible when a testtype 2 is being performed

```
        if ((int)testType == 2)
            indmetaL.Visible = false;
        if ((int)testType == 2)
            midmetaL.Visible = false;
        if ((int)testType == 2)
            rinmetaL.Visible = false;
        if ((int)testType == 2)
            litmetaL.Visible = false;
```

I have tried structuring these statements like this:

```
 if ((int)testType == 2)
       indmetaL.Visible = false;
       midmetaL.Visible = false;
       rinmetaL.Visible = false
       litmetaL.Visible = false;
```

however when I do the midmetaL, rinmetaL and litmetaL stay invisible during testtype 1

I am sure there is a way to set all these 'visible' properties to false in one line however I am not sure of the syntax, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @ChaosPandion he's probably just a Python developer writing Python code in C# ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((int)testType == 2)
{
       indmetaL.Visible = false;
       midmetaL.Visible = false;
       rinmetaL.Visible = false
       litmetaL.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something ridiculously simple, this is what I get for working too late, thank you :D

Comment: I think a bit more explanation is necessary for me to up vote. Such a fundamental concept should be understood before writing serious code.

Answer (score 2):

Either use curly braces to create code block:

```
if ((int)testType == 2)
{
   indmetaL.Visible = false;
   midmetaL.Visible = false;
   rinmetaL.Visible = false
   litmetaL.Visible = false;
}
```

or use chain assignment:

```
if ((int)testType == 2)
   indmetaL.Visible = midmetaL.Visible = rinmetaL.Visible = litmetaL.Visible = false;
```

Comment: whoa I didn't know you could do this in C# +1 for learning something new. May as well make it a one-liner and assign them all to `((int)testType == 2)

Answer (score 1):

You should use curly braces to define a [statement block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx) for the `if`, otherwise only the first line belongs to it. So this works:

```
if ((int)testType == 2)
{
    indmetaL.Visible = false;
    midmetaL.Visible = false;
    rinmetaL.Visible = false
    litmetaL.Visible = false;
}
```

[Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces)

Answer (score 1):

Use curly braces to group multiple statements into a block;

```
if ((int) testType == 2)
{
    indmetaL.Visible = false;
    midmetaL.Visible = false;
    rinmetaL.Visible = false;
    litmetaL.Visible = false;
}
```

In C#, the `if` statement conditionally executes only the immediately following statement or block. Thus, you need the curly braces. The same is generally true of other flow control statements such as `for`, `while`, etc.

Comment: Right, that's the point. But that may not be obvious to less experienced programmers. Thus I explicitly said "statement or block" in case one isn't familiar with that equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

use Switch statements. They are faster than if statements because they directly jump to the correct case.

```
switch((int)testType)
{
    case 2:
        indmetaL.Visible = false;
        midmetaL.Visible = false;
        rinmetaL.Visible = false;
        litmetaL.Visible = false;
    break;
}
```

or if you want if statement you can write it in a single line without curly braces like this

```
if((int)testType==2)
    indmetaL.Visible = midmetaL.Visible = rinmetaL.Visible = litmetaL.Visible = false;
```