# runtime memory error in recursive replace white space with character function in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a recursive funciton using static variable that would replace white space with asterik character however soemthing is amiss. I get error `Runtime error    time: 0 memory: 3472 signal:11`.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string replace(string s) {
    static int n = 0;

    if (n == s.length()) return s; 
    if (s[n] == ' ') s[n] = '*';

    n++;
    replace(s);
}

int main() {
    string s= "ssdfa sadfs";
    cout<<replace(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: If you want to make it recursive, why to calculate string leangh every time. You should pass string length as parameter to function. It will increase your computation time. Your function header should be like this ` string replace(string s, int len)`

Comment: So how would I be able to call `replace` more than once in a program?  Write it without the `static` variable.

Comment: You would need a wrapper function and another function that would be like `int count(string s, int n)` and this wrapper function would be like `string replace(string s) { return count(s,0); }`

Comment: @Shravan40 `std::string` doesn't need to calculate the length, it's a member of the structure. It's not like C strings, which require you to search for the terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only returning a string from the base case of the recursion, not all the other cases. Change the last line to:

```
return replace(s);
```

Comment: so basically error is due to that string function isn't returning anything

Comment: Yes. You get an error when you try to print the result, since there's no result.

Answer (score 1):

This can simply be done like this

```
string replace(string s)
{
    int len = s.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == ' ')
            s[i] = '*';
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: i want to do it using recursive, to practice recursive functions. I know it makes more sense to use loop here.