# JS / Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in JS:

```
if (all[j][i][11] != Boolean(1) && $scope.w[j][i] != undefined && $scope.ip[j][i] != undefined && $scope.type[j][i] != undefined)
            var specificArray = []
            specificArray.push($scope.w[j][i]);
            // continue with the code
```

it gives me the next error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

But specificArray is defined just before the push operation.

I also try: `var specificArray = new Array()`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add some curly braces on the condition

```
if (all[j][i][11] != Boolean(1) && $scope.w[j][i] != undefined && $scope.ip[j][i] != undefined && $scope.type[j][i] != undefined){
    var specificArray = []
    specificArray.push($scope.w[j][i]);
}
```

Without it the behavior is like this:

```
if (all[j][i][11] != Boolean(1) && $scope.w[j][i] != undefined && $scope.ip[j][i] != undefined && $scope.type[j][i] != undefined){
    var specificArray = [];
}
specificArray.push($scope.w[j][i]); // Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Comment: They're called "curly braces".