# PHP add values of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this, this array represents number of products in a shopping cart

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [icon] => bus.png
            [name] => Web Development
            [cost] => 500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [icon] => icon.png
            [name] => Icon design
            [cost] => 300
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [icon] => icon.png
            [name] => footer design
            [cost] => 300
        )

)
```

and i am trying to add the `[cost]` of each together, since it is a shopping cart I need to display the total. some people might buy single product or 2 or 3 so how do i display the total by adding the `cost` together I have tried using `array_sum($products['cost'])` and `array_sum($products[0]['cost'])` but that does not work

Comment: For PHP >= 5.5, `$total = array_sum(array_column($myArray, 'cost'));`

Comment: For earlier versions of PHP: `$total = array_sum(array_map(function($value) { return $value['cost']; }, $myArray));`

Comment: thanks @MarkBaker i will go with a solution on second commend, please add this as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP >= 5.5, you can take advantage of PHP's [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function

```
$total = array_sum(
    array_column(
        $myArray, 
        'cost'
    )
);
```

For earlier versions of PHP, you can emulate this using [array_map()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$total = array_sum(
    array_map(
        function($value) { 
            return $value['cost']; 
        }, 
        $myArray
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any built-in function than you can simply use old technique :)

```
$sum=0;
foreach ($old as $new) $sum+=$new['cost'];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Simple use foreach and sum it;

```
$sum=0;
foreach($product as $key => $value){
    $sum += $value['cost'];
}
```

Then if you want to sum only the selected products

```
$sum=0;
foreach($product as $key => $value){
    if(in_array($value['id'], $array_of_selected_product_ids))
        $sum += $value['cost'];
}
```