# How to use IF statement in TextBox's text change event

Tags: c#

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (a.Equals(b))
    {
        result = a.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = result;
        textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }
    else
        result = b.ToString();
    textBox1.Text = result;
    textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you are having problems with?  What's currently not working with your if statements?

Comment: Are you missing brackets for the else or is that intentional?

Comment: @Plue [that edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6829258) is invalid. Don't change the code of a question, especially since the missing brackets may be the source of the issue.

Comment: @CodeCaster sorry I thought I deleted it myself while editing

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you forgot to add brackets in your else statement.

Try this code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (a.Equals(b))
    {
        result = a.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = result;
        textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    }
    else
    {
        result = b.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = result;
        textBox1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }
}
```

It is always good practice to place curly brackets in `if`, `else` statements, `loops`, etc.

Read answers in this question: [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces)