# Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)

Tags: c, linux

Ima trying to debug my code using Valgrind, but I do have some problems w/ the read function.

Here is the Valgrind log :

```
==4333== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==4333==     at 0x4F0C600: __read_nocancel (in /lib64/libc-2.18.so)
==4333==     by 0x400AB7: my_read (get_next_line.c:132)
==4333==     by 0x400B6C: get_next_line (tmp.c:25)
==4333==     by 0x400B27: main (get_next_line.c:146)
==4333== Address 0x401000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==4333==
==4333==
==4333== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4333==    in use at exit : 4,106bytes in 1 blocks
==4333==  total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 4,106 bytes allocated
==4333==
==4333== 4,106 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==4333==    at 0x4C277AB: malloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4333==    by 0x400A59: my_read (get_next_line.c:129)
==4333==    by 0x400B6C: get_next_line (tmp.c:25)
==4333==    by 0x400B27: main (get_next_line.c:146)
==4333==
==4333== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4333==    definitely lost: 4,106 bytes in 1 blocks
```

And here is the code :

```
int    my_read(int fd)
{
  char *str;
  void *buff;
  int   x;

  str = NULL;
  if ((buff malloc(BUFFER_SIZE + 10)) == NULL)
     return (NULL);
  buff = NULL;
  while ((x = read(fd, buff, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) //LINE 132
     str = (str == NULL) ? my_strdup(buff) : my_strcat(buff, str);
  return (str);
}
```

BUFFER_SIZE is defined at 4096.

I understand the error, but I don't know how to carry this.
If you guys could help me fix this up, it would be awesome. Ty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: About-To-Be-Related: `buff malloc(...` - want to buy an *assignment* operator  (`=`) ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the

```
buff = NULL;
```

statement. After you allocate the space for `buffer`, you're forgetting that and overwriting it with `NULL`, and then using that when you call `read()`. Get rid of that statement.

You also need to `free(buff);` before you return from the function. Otherwise you'll leak memory every time you call `my_read()`.

And since you return a pointer, the function should be declared:

```
char * my_read(int fd)
```