# HTML form and javascript---show different form in same table

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 4 form in a HTML table,use 4 button to call the form out.

HTML:

```
<div id="myAccordion">
  <table id="edit"
         class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-nonfluid1 thumbnail">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width=50%>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-parent="#myAccordion"
                  id="cpass"
                  onclick="document.getElementById('col').style.display = 'inline'">form1
          </button>
        </td>
        <td width=50%>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-parent="#myAccordion"
                  id="cinfo"
                  onclick="document.getElementById('col').style.display = 'inline'">form2
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width=50%>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-parent="#myAccordion"
                  id="cmail"
                  onclick="document.getElementById('col').style.display = 'inline'">form3
          </button>
        </td>
        <td width=50%>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-parent="#myAccordion"
                  id="cplace"
                  onclick="document.getElementById('col').style.display = 'inline'">form4
          </button>
        </td>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="display:none;" id="col">
          <div id="form1" class="collapse">
            <form method="POST" action="updatepassc.php" novalidate="novalidate" id="1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="oldpassword" class="control-label ">1:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="oldpassword"
                       name="oldpassword">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="newpassword" class="control-label ">2:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newpassword"
                       name="newpassword">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="newpassword1" class="control-label ">3:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newpassword1"
                       name="newpassword1">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">yes</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div id="form2" class="collapse">
            .
            <form method="POST" action="updateinfo.php" novalidate="novalidate">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="newinfo" class="control-label ">2</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="newinfo"
                          name="newinfo">></textarea>
                <span class="help-block"></span>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">yes</button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div id="form3" class="collapse">
            .
            <form method="POST" action="updateinfo.php" novalidate="novalidate">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="newinfo" class="control-label ">3</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="newinfo"
                          name="newinfo">></textarea>
                <span class="help-block"></span>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">3</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div id="form4" class="collapse">
            .
            <form method="POST" action="updateinfo.php" novalidate="novalidate">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="newinfo" class="control-label ">4</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="newinfo"
                          name="newinfo"></textarea>
                <span class="help-block"></span>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">yes</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And i want to show different form in (td id="col"),but it have a error , it will show two form in same time.I want if i click a button,1 form will open , anther form will close.For example,if form 1 open,form 2,3,4 will close

This is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cpass').click(function () {
        $('#form1').collapse('show');
        if ($('#form2').is(':visible'))
            $('#form2').collapse('hide');
    });
    $('#cinfo').click(function () {
        $('#form2').collapse('show');
        if ($('#form1').is(':visible'))
            $('#form1').collapse('hide');
    });
    $('#cmail').click(function () {
        $('#form3').collapse('show');
        if ($('#form4').is(':visible'))
            $('#form4').collapse('hide');
    });
    $('#cplace').click(function () {
        $('#form4').collapse('show');
        if ($('#form3').is(':visible'))
            $('#form3').collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

The **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/oe8035os/1/)**

How can i fix the problem?

Comment: Don't put `<script>` in the Javascript panel of jsfiddle, it does that automatically for you.

Comment: It works when I fix that: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/oe8035os/1/

Comment: BTW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: Why do you use both inline `onclick` attributes and Javascript `.click()` functions?

Comment: Have you thought about setting the other forms to hidden in the same call as well?

Comment: @Barmar i want if one form open , anther form will close.

Comment: @Barmar For example , if form 1 open , form 2,3,4 will close

Comment: If you want to close 2, 3, and 4, why do you only do `$("#form2").collapse("hide")`?

Comment: @Barmar add $("#form3").collapse("hide") $("#form4").collapse("hide") ? How can i check if 2,3,4 is open?

Comment: Why do you need to check? Just close them all. If it's already closed, nothing will happen.

Comment: @Barmar Just add  $("#form3").collapse("hide") $("#form4").collapse("hide") in $('#cpass').click(function ()?

Comment: @paul0080 it would be easier to just do $("#form3,#form4,#form1).collapse("hide");

Comment: @  A.Sharma $("#form3,#form4,#form1).collapse("hide"); is not working.

Comment: I was just demonstrating the use of commas instead of doing multiple hide calls.  See my answer

Answer (score 0):

updated you jQuery code with slideUp and slideDown. it opens only one form at a time. also add a common meaningful class name for all the forms so that you can call hide/sildeUp without explicitly using multiple id/class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cpass').click(function () {
        $('#form1').slideDown();
        $('#form2,#form3,#form4').slideUp();
    });
    $('#cinfo').click(function () {
        $('#form2').slideDown();
        $('#form1,#form3,#form4').slideUp();
    });
    $('#cmail').click(function () {
        $('#form3').slideDown();
        $('#form1,#form2,#form4').slideUp();
    });
    $('#cplace').click(function () {
        $('#form4').slideDown();
        $('#form1,#form2,#form3').slideUp();
    });
});
```

edit: remove inline onclick and css for keeping the html clean

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qrk8L4g/2/)

Comment: This is a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are ways to simplify your JS code, I will keep the general format and modify it slightly for an effect. Note that you can use a comma to select multiple div objects.

You can make the code cleaner by adding an animation like rkamath suggested. His offers a slide effect. Here is a fade effect for your convenience as well:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#cpass').click(function () {
    $('#form2,#form3,#form4').hide();
    $('#form1').fadeIn();

});
$('#cinfo').click(function () {
    $('#form1,#form3,#form4').hide();
    $('#form2').fadeIn(); 

});
$('#cmail').click(function () {
    $('#form4,#form2,#form1').hide();
    $('#form3').fadeIn();

});
$('#cplace').click(function () {
    $('#form3,#form2,#form1').hide();
    $('#form4').fadeIn();

});
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe8035os/13/) for this.

If you really want to keep the general structure of your code here you go:

```
$('#cpass').click(function () {
    $('#form1').collapse('show');
    if ($('#form2,#form3,#form4').is(':visible'))   $('#form2,#form3,#form4').collapse('hide');
});

$('#cinfo').click(function () {
    $('#form2').collapse('show');
    if ($('#form1,#form3,#form4').is(':visible'))  
    $('#form1,#form3,#form4').collapse('hide');
});

$('#cmail').click(function () {
    $('#form3').collapse('show');
    if ($('#form4,#form2,#form1').is(':visible')) 
    $('#form4,#form2,#form1').collapse('hide');
});

$('#cplace').click(function () {
    $('#form4').collapse('show');
    if ($('#form3,#form2,#form1').is(':visible'))  
    $('#form3,#form2,#form1').collapse('hide');
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe8035os/10/).

Comment: When i use hide() in to my website ,the form can not show out ,just show out a null <td>

Comment: It works fine on the fiddle. If it doesn't work for you then just use the second option i posted. The second option should work for you based on the code you gave in your initial question.

Comment: If i using second option just can work once time only.

Comment: Try the second option again with the updated code. By second time do you mean that it doesn't work after you submit the form the first time?

Comment: If i click another form , it will show out all form in table

Comment: Is what is happening on your site the same thing that is happening in fiddle? Fiddle is working fine.

Comment: For example ,i click form 1 is ok but click form 2 is not working

Comment: What I'm saying is that clicking the forms in fiddle works every time. When you click in fiddle is what is happening there happening on your site as well? Do you have the same jquery plugins from the fiddle referenced on your site?

Comment: but third time will ok again

Answer (score -1):

Line 1, and 24 to 26 are not needed (the  are making your errors)

```
    });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oe8035os/3/)

Comment: There were no problems with those lines in his fiddle. The error was because of `<script>` lines. He's posted a new fiddle link without that.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that. I hit 23 instead of 24.