# Apply inline CSS to PHP preg_replace or str_replace function

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP function that is calling the following:

```
function availability_filter_func($availability) {
    $replacement =  'Out of Stock - Contact Us';
    if(is_single(array(3186,3518)))
        $availability['availability'] = str_ireplace('Out of stock', $replacement, $availability['availability']);
}
```

As you can see I am replacing the text string with custom text, however 
I need the "Contact Us" text to be `<a href="mailto:contact@example.com">Contact Us </a>` - how would I go about doing this? Inputting raw html into the replacement string makes the html a part of the output.

Echo does not work and breaks the PHP function - same with trying to escape the PHP function, inserting html on on the entire string, and unescape the function.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: [Why is it bad practice to omit curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)

Comment: If you're seeing the HTML in the output, the problem is with how you're outputting it. You must be calling `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` on the string, which encodes all the HTML markup. If you want to be able to put HTML into the string, you mustn't do that.

Comment: Changing `str_ireplace("Out of stock", htmlentities("<p style="color:red">This text is red</p>")` results in the PHP script breaking. I have also tried `str_ireplace("Out of stock", htmlentities('<p style="color:red">This text is red</p>')`

Comment: In both your examples ^ you're not closing the `str_ireplace` function, you're only close the `htmlentities`. Also why are you running the htmlentitites, don't you want the HTML outputted?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be a complex way of doing this

```
function availability_filter_func($availability) {
    $default = "Out of Stock";
    $string = "<a href='mailto:contact@example.com'>Contact Us</a>";
    if($availablity !== "") {
        $return = $availability;
    } else {
        $return = $default;
    }
    return "$return - $string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Heredoc Syntax

```
$replacement = <<<LINK 
<a href="mailto:contact@example.com">Contact Us</a>
LINK;
```