# JavaScript . could not understand why my first console statement gives an undefined

Tags: javascript, console.log

```
function person(name){

   this.name1 = "His";

   this.day = {};
   this.day.time="kokok";


    this.check = function(name){

    for(var i in this)  console.log(this["i"]);

    if(this.name1===name) console.log("ready"+this.day.time);
     };
 }


 var t= new person("His");
 t.check("His");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be:

```
 console.log(this[i]);
```

instead of:

```
 console.log(this["i"]);
```

You want to reference the variable `i`, not a string `"i"`.