# "Scoping" C ++ compilation Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, pthreads

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the following error:

> trainLine.cpp:108: error: name lookup of ‘i’ changed for new ISO ‘for’ scoping
>
> trainLine.cpp:98: error:   using obsolete binding at ‘i’

Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
int main()
{
  pthread_t tidArray[NUM_TRAINS];
  Train* trainArray[NUM_TRAINS];

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRAINS;  i++)
    trainArray[i] = new Train(TRAIN_NAME_ARRAY[i], TRAIN_TRANSIT_TIME_MSECS[i]);

  int trainInd = 0;

  pthread_create(&tidArray[i], NULL, initiallyNorthernly,(void*)&trainArray[i]);

  pthread_create(&tidArray[i], NULL, initiallySouthernly,(void*)&trainArray[i]);

  for  (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRAINS;  i++)
    trainArray[i] = NULL;

  pthread_join(tidArray[i], (void**)&trainInd);

  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I apologize in advance, but I am very new to C/C++ and nothing is popping out as wrong to me. Possibly not placing brackets around for loop statements? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you expect `i` to be outside of those loops?

Comment: you're probably forgot braces that create compount statement: `for(...) { trainArr[i] = ...; pthread_create(...); }` Also, why do you create two threads in the same object `tidArray[i]`, it is incorrect

Comment: Yes, "not placing brackets around for loop statements", as you suspect. (But didn't attempt to do anything about, apparently.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: It strikes me as interesting that you're new enough to C to not know about enclosing statements in `{`/`}` compound blocks for loops (and other control structures, I guess), but you're diving into pthreads already?  It seems that you would have done at least one example program between "hello world" and multi-threaded C.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `i` exists only inside the `for`-loop, but you're trying to use it outside the loop.

Something like this could solve the problem, without altering the effect of the code:

```
  // ...
  int i = 0; // i is now accessible outside the loop as well
  for  (;  i < NUM_TRAINS;  i++)
    trainArray[i] = new     Train(TRAIN_NAME_ARRAY[i],TRAIN_TRANSIT_TIME_MSECS[i]);

  // use i, which is equal to NUM_TRAINS at this point
```

Comment: It's certainly not what he wants, though, as then his subsequent access are out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
pthread_join(tidArray[i], (void**)&trainInd);
```

you're referencing `i`, which is out of scope. I'm guessing you actually wanted this to be part of a loop, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TRAINS; ++i)
    pthread_join(tidArray[i], (void**)&trainInd);
```