# the sum of divisor (other than itself)

Tags: c

Write a program that reads integer from the keyboard and, on the output, writes the sum of the divisors of n (other than itself).

I've created a method that finds the sum of divisor. Using the while statement I can have up to 10 integers entered by the user until EOF. In the while statement I had sum = the output of sum_divisor and print out sum.

If I enter 0 0 0 4 5 6 12 then the output should be 0 0 0 3 1 6 16.
The output I get is  0 0 0 3 4 10 26. How can I make it so that it doesn't add the sum_divisor to the previous sum?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_divisor(int x);

int main()
{
    int x;
    int sum;
    printf("Enter up to 10 positive integer ending with EOF:\n");

    while((scanf("%d",&x)) != EOF){
        sum = sum_divisor(x);
        printf("%d ", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}

int sum_divisor(int x){

    int i;
    int sum;

    if(x<= 0){
        sum = 0;
    }
    else{
        for(i=1;i<x;++i)
            {
                if(x%i==0)
                    sum += i;
            }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Side issue:  Do not test against `EOF`, test against what is expected. `while((scanf("%d",&x)) == 1)`.  Had input been `"x"` instead of numeric input, code would have an infinite loop.

Comment: Why does the prompt say that there can only be up to 10 inputs? There's nothing in the code that cares how many inputs there are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialise `sum` to zero within your function. Otherwise, it will be set to some arbitrary value and the `else` block will have an arbitrary result.

In other words, change:

```
int sum;
```

into:

```
int sum = 0;
```

Of course, once you've done that, there's no need to explicitly do anything for the case where `x` is less than one. In addition, the initial `if` is superfluous since the `for` body won't execute when `x` is less than one, so you could get away with something like:

```
int sumDivisors (int x) {
    int i, sum = 0;

    for (i = 1 ; i < x; i++) {
        if ((x % i) == 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

As an aside, the values you're actually seeing *without* the initialisation are accumulating:

```
 0 ->  0
 0 ->  0
 0 ->  0
 3 ->  3
 1 ->  4
 6 -> 10
16 -> 26
```

This is almost certainly because each call to the function is reusing the same memory for the stack frame, including the variable `sum`, so `sum` is simply being added to each time (that the passed-in parameter is greater than one).

However, that's simply an artifact of the implementation, it's not guaranteed by the standard, which states quite clearly in `C11 6.7.9 Initialization /10`:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is ***indeterminate.***

In other words, *don't* rely on this.

---

And, as yet *another* aside, it's a mathematical given that, if a number `n` divides evenly by `a`, it also divides evenly by `n/a`. You can use this to your advantage to possibly make the code a little more efficient (though, as with *all* optimisations, you should *measure, not guess*).

Since you're discounting the number itself as a divisor, you have to treat the divisor `1` as a special case. You also have to treat perfect squares as a special case so that you don't add the square root twice.

The following code would be a good starting point for that:

```
int sumDivisors (int x) {
    int i, sum;

    // Always return zero for -inf..1 inclusive.

    if (x < 2)
        return 0;

    // Otherwise, 1 is factor, search for others
    //   up to but NOT including sqrt(x).
    for (i = 2, sum = 1 ; i * i < x; i++) {
        if ((x % i) == 0) {
            sum += i;
            sum += x / i;
        }
    }

    // Add in sqrt(x) ONCE for a perfect square.

    if (i * i == x)
        sum += i;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: And if this is done, he doesn't need the `if`. The `for` loop will end immediately if `x < 1`.

Comment: [please add in the curly braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)

Comment: That's a stylistic issue, nothing to do with the question per se. I happen to be from the school that prefers to see as much vertical code on the screen at once but I do understand *why* people prefer braces always.

Comment: Yes, it's stylistic. And when answering questions for newbies, I believe we should promote good style in addition to just answering the question.

Comment: @Barmar, I didn't say braces were *good* style, I said it was a stylistic issue. That means there's pros *and* cons on both sides of the issue, as evidenced by the fact the question you link to was closed as likely to "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" :-) In any case, I've added a note to that effect if you prefer the brace style, and religious wars should probably be fought on the battlefields of `<insert your favorite religious battlefield here>` rather than here on SO :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94042/discussion-between-paxdiablo-and-barmar).

Comment: I don't feel like debating it. I was making a stylistic suggestion. If you don't agree, fine.

Comment: @Barmar, actually I'll put them in. Since it only adds two lines to the code (and doesn't really affect vertical space *that* much), I realise I'm probably just being overly rigid, and possibly a *little* bit pig-headed :-) Cheers.

Comment: Like the `i*i`.  Goes from O(n) to O(sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 1):

When you call sum_divisor inside the while statement the same block of stack is being allocated, and therefore the sum variable is allocated in the same position on every call. At the first call the value is 0,(but not necessarily), the next time the value will be the one you calculated on the previous call.

`int sum = 0;` should fix it.

Comment: The initial value of an uninitialized local variable is undefined. It's just pure luck that it wasn't overwritten with garbage between the calls.

Comment: That is why i placed the (but not necessarily). Actually  if a bigger number was placed received by the scanf we would get part od the trash on sum resulting form the scanf filling the stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum_divisor(int x){
    if(x <= 0) { // you do not need to even alocate space for i an sum if x < 1.
      return 0;
    }

    int i = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    for(i=1;i<x;++i)
    {
        if(x%i==0)
            sum += i;

    }
    return sum;
}
```