# Difference between using brackets in for loop C# and not using it

Tags: c#, for-loop, difference, brackets

The output of the following code is different from the ouput from the second code 
can someone explain the problem?

Code 1:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= intInput; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++)
    {
        Console.Write('+');
        Console.WriteLine();
    }                         
}
if intInput is 4 Ouput is:
+
+
+ 
+
```

Code 2:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= intInput; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++)
        Console.Write('+');
        Console.WriteLine();                                    
}
if intInput is 4 Ouput is:

+
++
+++
++++
```

I know how this line of codes works but i dont understand what difference the brackets make on both codes?

Comment: If you don't specify curly braces it will consider first statement immediate to the for statement as inside the for loop to be repeatable.

Comment: looks like some kind of homework. Why you don't use the debugger to find out yourself?

Comment: Or you are a Python programmer. :) In Visual Studio, I always always use ctrl+k, ctrl+d to format the document, and then you also see nested if/for/class/whatever code a lot better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write;

```
for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
{
    Console.Write('+');
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Both `Console` line works until `j` loops out.

But when you write

```
for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    Console.Write('+');
    Console.WriteLine();
```

*Only* first `Console` works until `j` loops out. That's why second one is equal to;

```
for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++)
{
   Console.Write('+');
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

If there is *one* statement included in the loop, the curly brackes can be omitted. But using them is **always** a better approach.

Read: [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces)

Answer (score 4):

You second case effectively means:

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= intInput; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            Console.Write('+');
        }
        Console.WriteLine();                                    
    }
```

Indentation means nothing for compiler it is only for you

Comment: you used Python to much!

Comment: @kame Yeb bro Its true:)

Answer (score 2):

The loop has a scope. If you do not include the braces, only the first line is in the loop. If you have the braces, everything inside falls under the scope of the loop.

In this case, the first example write a "+" to the console as well as a new line every iteration of the inner loop.

The second case, the inner loop only executes the "+" writing on each inner iteration. The outer loop adds the new line.

Answer (score 0):

If alter 1 with **i** in second loop then it will work same

```
for (int j = **i**; j <= i; j++)
   Console.Write('+');
   Console.WriteLine();
```