# Is if (condition) try {...} legal in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, language-lawyer

For example:

```
if (true) try
{
    // works as expected with both true and false, but is it legal?
}
catch (...)
{
    // ...
}
```

In other words, is it legal to put the try-block *right after the if condition*?

Comment: Yes [it's illegal]. The try block should be within the `if` statement. But why not just test the condition using try?

Comment: @franklin No, it is not illegal.

Comment: Correct, it's not illegal. The brackets for the true-clause are optional in C and C++, and it's assumed whatever follows the if() is the true clause, and that a catch-clause that follows a try-clause is associated with that try-clause. Lots of companies' style guides will still gig you for not using the brackets, though.

Comment: `int main() try {} catch(...){}` is also legal.

Comment: @nwp: That is amazing! It looks like it's a new "feature" in C++0x. The motivation seems to be to allow constructor-initializers to be covered by the try/catch (e.g. `class foo { int bar; foo() try : bar(3) { ... } catch ...`).

Comment: It's legal but should be indented, as both try and catch are subject to the if condition

Comment: It's essentially an indentation issue. But perhaps the format is confusing because it bears syntactic similarities with [function-try-blocks](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block).

Comment: @ruakh: It's been present since the start. Not new in C++11.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The syntax of a `try` block (which is a [statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements) in C++) is

```
try compound-statement handler-sequence
```

And the syntax of `if` is:

```
attr(optional) if ( condition ) statement_true      
attr(optional) if ( condition ) statement_true else statement_false
```

where:

> `statement-true` - any statement (often a compound statement), which
>   is executed if condition evaluates to true
>  `statement-false` - any
>   statement (often a compound statement), which is executed if condition
>   evaluates to false

So yes, your code is legal code in `C++`.

`statement_true` in your case is a `try` block.

In legality, it is similar to:

```
if (condition) for(...) {
    ...
}
```

**But** your code is not very readable and can be the victim of some C++ pitfalls when an `else` is added. So, it is advisable to add explicit `{...}` after `if` in your case.

Comment: I think that grammar is irrelevant to the code presented by OP, isn't it?

Comment: @AngelusMortis If not grammar, what else would decide whether the piece of code is legal or not?

Comment: @AngelusMortis I was not trying to prove you are wrong. I put my point to discuss forward and understand your point of view about how could I make this answer more informative.

Comment: @AngelusMortis For example looking at [for loop syntax or grammar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) I can say `for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {...}` is legal but `for(int i = 0; i < 20; i > 16; int j = 24) {...}` is not.

Comment: @MohitJain: Actually, the C++ language isn't fully specified by its grammar. E.g. `int x; int x;` is a simple example that's allowed by the grammar but illegal nonetheless.

Comment: @MSalters Agreed. But I believe in this question concern of OP was to check whether the code is well-formed from syntax point of view. I mean syntax is one way to check whether the code is well formed.

Comment: Well, he asks whether it's legal, and that means it must be _permitted_ by the grammar, _and_ not banned by other rules. The grammar describes a superset of the valid C++ programs. But it's hard to prove a negative, of course.

Comment: @MSalters You are right. The intent of the question is to ask whether the code snippet as it stands is well formed C++ code.

Comment: On the topic of brace-placement style:  I wonder what the actual danger here is.  I don't immediately see any at all.  "if (c1) if (c2) s1; else s2;" can confuse some people, and can occasionally lead some people to attach an "else" to the wrong "if".  But I don't see that danger with try-catch.

Comment: @mjwach See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: @Barmar Nobody seems to advocate braces in try-catch there; it's mostly about if-else.  But some people do point out the danger that in "if (c) s1; s2;" some careless maintainer will comment out the "s1" line and thus apply the "if" to s2, which could happen with braceless try-catch as well.  I suppose that's a good enough answer to the question of what the danger might be (though by itself it doesn't strike me as justification for REQUIRING braces).

Comment: @mjwach Actually, the more common problem with braceless if-else is adding a print statement while debugging. You're right that try-catch is different because the `catch` keyword makes that a syntax error. But once you get in the habit of putting braces around all blocks, I think it's best style to use them consistently everywhere.

Comment: @LeoHeinsaar But language pitfalls are real

Comment: @MohitJain: I think your quote from the standard and then *your* claim that *"`statement_true` in your case is a `try` block"* lacks proof, because the quote does not say whether try-block is `statement_true` or not. All it says `if` block can be defined in terms of `statement_true`, but it does *not*  define what `statement_true` is, does it? In that sense, your quote from the standard is meaningless and irrelevant to *your* claim because you did not *connect* all the mandatory text from the standard to back your claim.

Comment: Thanks @Nawaz for valuable input. You are right I assumed the meaning of text in syntax is clear and did not bother to explicitly add the details and left a gap in proof.

Answer (score 40):

> is it legal to put the try-block right after the if condition?

It is legal. Your code is same as (and better to write as):

```
if (true) {
    try
    {
        // works as expected with both true and false, but is it legal?
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So if the condition is `false` then the `try-catch` block won't be executed. If this is what you expect, it's fine.

Comment: If you remove the outermost `{` and `}` braces, the equivalence becomes trivially obvious.

Comment: I agree. It's just that removing the braces makes it obvious that the `if` statement in the original question is _exactly the same_ not counting spaces. Without braces, your formatting reveals that there's nothing "magical" in putting a _try-catch_ block right after the `if` statement.

Comment: As long as we're promoting good style, shouldn't the code stick to one or the other bracing style? Or is this meant to make everyone equally dissatisfied? ;)

Comment: Not sure I agree that this is better or more readable. This is more traditional, certainly, but ops way reads more like an english sentence, where as this reads like code. Apples and oranges maybe, but equally readable, and equally correct imho. This is like if blocks with a single, short statement. I'm for putting that statement on the same line and doing away with the braces. If it's all on the same line, you'd have to be blind not to realise you need to add braces if you want to add something to the block, and I believe most IDEs will insert the braces for you anyway (don't quote me though)

Answer (score 22):

Yes. The braces of an `if` are optional. Imagine you have `{}` around the `try { .. } catch { .. }`.

It may interest you to know that this is what happens when you write `if`/`else if`/`else`; C++ doesn't actually have `else if` … so this:

```
if (A) {

}
else if (B) {

}
```

is actually parsed as this:

```
if (A) {

}
else
   if (B) {

   }
```

which is this:

```
if (A) {

}
else {
   if (B) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Lightning strikes :p

Comment: `C++ doesn't actually have else if` Whoooa

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 There is no excplicit `elseif` token such as can be found in some languages.  The `if` part of the `else if` construct is a whole new statement, and this causes some interesting misunderstandings in code that doesn't recognize it as such.

Comment: @Corey Yes that's what my answer says

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Which is why I commented instead of answering :)

Answer (score 9):

It's well-formed. *try-block*s are *statement*s as per [[stmt.stmt]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#1), and *statement*s are following `if (…)` as per [[stmt.select]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.select#1).