# If ... else switch ... statement

Tags: c, gcc

Following code compiles on my gcc 5.4.0, doesn't generate any warnings and works fine:

```
if (a == 0) {
    puts("0");
} else switch (a) {
    case 1: puts("1"); break;
    case 2: puts("2"); break;
    default: puts("default"); break;
}
```

Is *if ... else switch ...* correct statement?

Comment: Correct, yes. Formatted horribly, yes.

Comment: Similar question in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985592/is-if-condition-try-legal-in-c/35985655#35985655

Comment: Related fun fact: The C language actually does not have an `else if` statement. It is an `else` statement without braces followed by another `if` statement. `else if(a==b){ }` is a brace-less, strangely indented version of `else /* new line */ { if(a==b){} }`.

Comment: @Lundin That's right. IMO many books and tutorials suggest that `else if` is a statement but actually it is not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The [grammar for `if` ... `else`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) is as follows:

> attr(optional) **if** ( condition ) statement-true **else** statement-false

`switch` is a statement, so it is allowed to go after `else`.

---

Note that `else if` is not a special construct either, it's just an `if` statement after an `else`.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is syntactically correct... but it does not make easy reading.

You will likely be pulled up on it if your code is being reviewed - because you're making use of an "*un-braced, multi-line statement as part of a conditional*".

Prefer to be explicit and write it like so:

```
if (a == 0) {
    puts("0");
} else {
    switch (a) {
        case 1: puts("1"); break;
        case 2: puts("2"); break;
        default: puts("default"); break;
    }
}
```

---

It is legal in the same way that the following is legal:

```
if (a == 0)
    puts("0");
else
    puts("not0");
```

Such constructs can lead to mistakes when re-visiting the code... I seem to remember that one of the recent "popular" vulnerabilities was implemented (by mistake... hopefully) in part due to this "*un-braced*" use of `if`.

Answer (score 3):

The `switch` is a statement, so this is just putting a statement in the `else`.

It's no different from

```
else
  a = 0;
```

or

```
else
{
  switch(a)
  {
  case 1:
  ...
  }
}
```

It's not a very common way of writing it, but it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with your code, that is the same of writing this:

```
if (a == 0) {
    puts("0");
} else {
    switch (a) {
        case 1: puts("1"); break;
        case 2: puts("2"); break;
        default: puts("default"); break;
    }
}
```

That is perfectly legit. `else switch` is not a real statement. 
Your statement is

```
if(condition){code block} else {code block}
```

`code block` can contain any statement, such as your `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of `if` is:

```
if ( condition ) statement-true  else statement-false
condition is an expression convertible to a boolean (true/false)
statement-true is a statement which is executed if condition is true
statement-false is a statement which is executed if condition is false
```

And `switch` block is a statement.

So yes, your code exhibit correct statement.