# how to use scanf in a custom function in C

Tags: c

Before I start please keep in mind that I am still learning and need help with some stuff that may be easy to you but not to me. So here we go. I am having trouble using scanf in a custom function. It will not let me type anything. It just keeps running forever unless I stop it. How can I get scanf to work here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function ();

int main (void)
{
  char sel;
  function ();
  return 0;
}

void function ()
{
  scanf("%c",&sel);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing what it is you're trying to do and what behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Please explain 'trouble'.  What 'trouble'?

Comment: Could you give a more detailed description about how your program isn't working? What are you using to compile it? How are you compiling it with that? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Just trying to help out with general coding, try not to use global variables unless they're necessary, it would be enough if it's local to main. There's no point in creating a function with only calls scanf with a global variable.

Comment: @jacobgarner Don't remove curly braces around loop body: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: @MartinJames it will not let me type anything in. Nor will it print if you use printf.

Comment: Well now you have `function()` trying to access a variable that's local to `main()`.

Comment: When you ask questions about code, you really should copy and paste the exact code.  It's also weird that you completely changed the code after you asked the question, and the accepted answer makes *no* sense with the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with scanf. The problem is with your loop. `l = 1` and `l++` will always keep `l >= 0` and hence it will keep on taking input infinite times.
Also, it will keep on overriding the value of `var.a` with every input

Comment: Ok. but..I need a loop (of any type) to keep going forward forever. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to take the input infinitely? If yes, then the above code has no issues. What is the problem you are facing in scanf then?

Comment: Yes, but it won't even let me type anything in. I even got rid of the loop and it did the same thing happened!

Comment: @JacobGarner: I compiled your program as it is, and it lets me type things in. How are you compiling, and how are you running it?

Comment: Even me! There is no problem in your code if you want to take input for infinite number of times ( Though it doesn't make sense to me ) . You can do printf below your scanf to see your code working

Comment: @amaurea I compile it in CCP (that is the C language type)

Comment: @PriyanshGoel that won't work either.

Comment: I suppose that you are making a .c file and compiling it using cc/gcc command

Comment: @PriyanshGoel it says that my C-language is in CCP

Comment: @JacobGarner What's that supposed to mean, .cpp is traditionally the file extension for C++ files, not C if that's what you mean, but I have no idea what CCP is.

Comment: Do avoid integer overflow. `l >= 0` -> `l < INT_MAX` after including `limits.h`, or simply `for(;;)` because `l` is not used in the loop.

Comment: @lemondrop my compiler does not have options for what you're talking about. So I assume it's the same.

Comment: 1. It will not be "infinite" numbr of time. 2. The call to `scanf()` is wrong because there is no checking of the return value.