# if statement syntax clarification

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Beast Mode ON</title>

<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var name = prompt("Please enter your name: ");
if (name == null || name == "") name = " visitor "
{document.write("Hi " + name + " welcome to javascript.");}
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

this code works accurately. the question i wanna raise is WHY? because the "if" statement executes the codes in curly braces only if the condition in the paretheses is met. but if i try to incorporate parentheses like

```
if ((name == null || name == "") name = " visitor ")
```

the code stops working. what's the reason?

Comment: The code in the curly braces [always runs.](https://jsfiddle.net/u002zhng/) What do you think `if((name == null | name == "") name = " visitor ")` should do? Basically, it's like writing `if ((true)name = "visitor")`. It's syntactically invalid, doesn't denote a block, and implies that you can do things like `(true)name` and expect a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (name == null || name == "") name = " visitor "
{document.write("Hi " + name + " welcome to javascript.");}
```

This is incorrect syntax.

What it is saying (and doing) is this:

```
if (name == null || name == "") {
      name = "visitor";
   }
document.write("Hi " + name + " welcome to javascript.");
```

name = "visitor" is not a condition. It is an assignment.

In your code, the braces around the `document.write...` are useless and do nothing for the if statement.

You don't have to use braces around a one line if statement, but the correct way to write this would be:

```
if (name == null || name == "") 
    name = "visitor";
document.write("Hi " + name + " welcome to javascript.");
```

The above will only work if there is only one line to the code executed after the condition. Any other code is executed outside of the if.

Answer (score 1):

The general structure of `if` is:

```
if (condition) thingToDo
```

When the `condition` expression is true, it executes the code in `thingToDo`. (I've deliberately left out the optional `else` clause, as it's not relevant to this question.)

So in your first block of code, `condition` is `name == null || name == ""` and `thingToDo` is `name = " visitor "`. So if the user enters an empty name in response to the prompt, it sets name to `" visitor "` in its place.

If `thingToDo` contains multiple statements, you have to wrap them in curly braces to make it a block of code. But if it's just a single statement, the braces are optional (although I recommend them, see [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)). The braces around the `document.write()` call are irrelevant, as that is outside the `if` statement.

Your second attempt is wrong because you've change the condition to:

```
(name == null || name == "") name = " visitor "
```

This is not a valid expression -- you've moved the assignment inside the condition, but there's no operator connecting it with the comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Its because, it is incorrect syntax

```
if ((name == null || name == "") name = " visitor ")"
```

if is not being closed correctly

It should be something like this

```
if((name==null||name=="")) name="visitor";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Where do you see `")"` in his code?

Comment: @Barmar It's just a typo.

Comment: @Barmar Just forget about the last double-quote mark and it'll make sense.

Comment: @AmericanPatriot But there's no last `)` either. The question just says `name = " visitor "`, which is not a syntax error.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. His question isn't about the code in the code block, it's about the different code in the text, which isn't highlighted so I could see it.

Comment: @Barmar Look at the last line of code in the question again. There are, in fact, a total of 4 parentheses in that statement. The `)` in this answer closes the first `(` on that same line.

Comment: @AmericanPatriot I know, I said I understand now. I edited the question to make it easier to see what code he was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 suggestions

1. the correct code would be

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var name = prompt("Please enter your name: ");
    if (name == null || name == "") 
    {
        name = 'visitor';
    }
    document.write("Hi " + name + " welcome to javascript.");
</script>
```

2. please use single quote in javascript instead of double quote.
3. its better to use a library to check for all false cases of a variable. Since it could also be undefined. This also makes it easier to read. You could use the library lodash and write `if(_.isString(name))`

Comment: Why use single quotes instead of double quotes? That's just personal style, there's no reason to prefer one.

Comment: You've broken the functionality though. The idea of the `if` is to see if they should change `name` to `" visitor "` when the user didn't enter anything. Whether they entered anything or not, it should be writing out the message.

Comment: thanks... i got this. but my curiosity was regarding the  visitor part.. how there came to be a condition out of the parentheses ?

Comment: well if you are goin to mix javascript and html its easier using different kind of quotes.

Comment: @CGChristenChristensen That's true, but they both allow either kind of quotes, so you can use double in JS and single in HTML, or vice versa.

Comment: @MikeC so I just changed the code, I guess this would make the most sense then.

Comment: @Barmar you can do many things, but if you want other people to read your code, you should use double quotes in html and single qoutes in javascript. That is what most people expect.

Comment: I don't agree with that statement at all and I've been working in the industry for years.

Comment: That's news to me. I've been here for years and never noticed a concensus one way or the other.

Comment: @CGChristenChristensen I prefer single quotes because that means I don't have to press Shift when I'm typing them but they're by no means an industry standard. Everyone has their own preference and, truth be told, your HTML and JavaScript should seldom, if ever, meet so that kind of throws your argument out.

Comment: I agree that HTML and JS shouldn't meet :) but regarding the quotes I guess we have different opinions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31883471/1814303

Comment: guys thanks a lot for such an overwhelming response. acutally i was trying this snnipet from a book and wondering how an if statement could be extended out of the parenthesis. but as explained by @CG Christen the    name = "visitor" was actually and assignement, not the conditional. Anyways, you completely nailed it. now it has been cemented in the deepest part of my neurons.