# Comments in if statement without curly braces

Tags: c, if-statement, comments

Let's say we have this C code snippet:

```
if (condition)
    x = a;
else
    x = b;
```

Is it allowed to insert comments like this, without changing the semantics of the code:

```
if (condition)
    /* blah blah blah */
    x = a;
else
    x = b;
```

*(if there were curly braces, the answer would be obviously yes, but what about these cases of if statements without curly braces?)*

Comment: You can do this, but it is very poor style.

Comment: Comments are replaced by a single space in [phase 3](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases#Phase_3) of translation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But, is the resulting code (taht will contain an emply line) valid?

Comment: @VividD Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Yes, you can do this - comments are stripped (replaced by a single space character)  by the preprocessor before any syntax analysis occurs, and whitespace is not meaningful except to separate tokens.  Having said that, I would use the curly braces regardless.

Comment: If a line is empty or only contain white-space, it's not a statement. And the `if` block needs *a* statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments have no effect on the code other than the fact that they help to understand and edit code later.

The code you have shown is valid.

**If the `if` statement is followed by codes inside curly braces all the codes inside the brace will get executed if the condition for `if` is met.
If there is no curly braces to group the code, the statement immediately after the `if` statement gets executed. If there is comments before this statement it will not effect the code as the comments will be removed when the code is compiled.**

Comment: The expression "If the if statement..." sounds clintonesque ("It depends on what the meaning of the word is is.") - http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/chatterbox/1998/09/bill_clinton_and_the_meaning_of_is.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Comments are simply ignored and can be put anywhere that whitespace is allowed.

But I strongly urge you not to write `if` statements without curly braces. See [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is a blank line allowed inside of multiline macros?

Comment: A completely blank - no. It has to have `\\`.

Comment: Right. The comment is replaced by whitespace, but the extra newline is still there, so it acts the same as putting whitespace in the macro.

Comment: @Barmar I always follow the advice to use curly braces, however, in some projects, coding standards are enforced, and they may require not using curly braces for one line if...

Comment: @VividD Really? I have never seen such a code standards. They are clearly against every good coding practice I have heard about.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I would refrain from mentioning the name of such project, but it is a significant one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the comments are not considered in the compilation and, therefore, does not change the semantics of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can add comments as u wish.Compiler simply ignores multi-line as well as single line comments comments