# How can I add numbers entered by the user using while or for loop in c++?

Tags: c++

It's really complicated to me as a beginner to do it so I tried this code :

```
    int x,sum=0;

while (x)
    cin >> x;
    sum+=x;
    cout << sum ;
```

I want to let the program when the user enters "0" the program should print the sum of these numbers entered by the user.

Comment: Your indentation is confusing you. A `while` will only execute the next statement in the absence of curly braces.

Comment: Indentation has no impact on the code execution. As your loop is written, **only** the `cin >> x;` would be executed inside the loop. Consider learning from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) rather than trying to code randomly.

Comment: Should I use for instead of while?

Comment: @MohamedMagdy You should surround the code, you wanted to be exucted inside a loop, in braces (`{`/`}`). Otherwise, only the first statement would be executed.

Comment: ***Should I use for instead of while?*** No that will not help fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is here:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
   int x;
   int sum = 0;

   std::cin >> x;

   while(x)
   {
      sum += x;
      std::cin >> x;
   }

   std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

You are missing `{}`s around the statements in your `while` loop, so only `cin >> x` gets executed.

Comment: it worked fine, thanks

Comment: I have a few issues with this solution. For instance, if the stream fails you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Of course, that's true. But as the author of OP seems to be very new in programming and does not even know proper syntax, I wanted to make it as simple as possible for him.