# Is 'If Else' statement indentation important or not in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Does the indentation in an *if else* statement have any bearing on the execution of the code or is it just something to do for cleaner code?

Example from the book *[Accelerated C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Koenig_(programmer)#Books)* written by [Andrew Koening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Koenig_(programmer)):

```
while(c != cols) {
    if(r == pad + 1 && c == pad + 1) {
      cout << greet;
      c += greet.size();

    } else {

      if(r == 0 || r == rows - 1 || c == 0 || c == cols - 1)
        cout << "*";

      else
        cout << " ";
        ++c;
    }
  }
```

The prefix increment of `c` is executed regardless of whether r=0 or not, but I don’t understand why.

If the *if* statement turns true, an asterisk is printed. *If* not, a blank space is printed and `c` is incremented.
That’s how I am reading it, but `c` gets incremented regardless of what the values of `r` or `c` are.

This is what it says in the book, but there isn’t any explanation I could find:

> Notice how the different indentation of
> ++c;
> draws attention to the fact that it is executed regardless of whether we are in the
> border.

Comment: Put another way, you could put everything except preprocessor directives on the same line and it would still compile, producing the same behavior.

Comment: Is that really how `++c;` is indented in the book? I'll bet it actually lines up with `if` and `else`, not with `cout`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: That should be what it means by "the different indentation of ++c"

Comment: Indentation only serves to aid or deceive the reader.  The code in your example deceives.

Comment: My bikeshedding rule of thumb is to always use curly braces `{...}` for the body of an `if`/`else`.  But C++ does not require them for a single statement body.  That's just me; other people have strong opinions in favor never using optional curly braces.  Indentation is another perennial bikeshedding topic.  There are no right answers, only strong opinions.  These kinds of topics are best discussed over good beer.

Comment: Um... let python be strong with author of that code... No, indentation doesn't affect it and if code was written like that , I assume: a) that was typographic mistake , or b) author was pulling reader's leg.

Comment: @Eljay excellent  plan, but first we must agree on what constitutes good beer.

Comment: Did the indentation of that code get mangled in translation?

Comment: @user4581301 Possibly, but not according to the text in the yellow box.  Anyway, it's hideous, the answer to the _title_ of the question is yes, but the answer to the first line of the question is no.

Comment: @user4581301• good beer is the beer I like.  Bad beer is the beer that is indented wrong or puts the curly braces in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Whitespace does not affect C++ runtime behavior. (Unlike certain other languages, like Python).

I should mention that in your `else` block, you do not use braces.  So, only the first statement (`cout << " ";`) will be part of the `else` clause.  The subsequent `++c;` will execute regardless of the value of `r` and `c`.

Note that this last point is subjective, so take it with a grain of salt...  As you can see, when braces are omitted from `if ... else ...` blocks, there is potential for confusion.  Some would argue that it leads to more concise code, but many (including myself) would argue that you should always use braces.  This is especially important when you work on a large team because code tends to grow over time.  I've seen many cases in production code where an `if` statement was missing the braces and someone added a second line to the `if` clause without remembering to add braces.  This didn't work as expected and caused wasted time debugging fails, just because the braces were omitted.

Comment: Your second paragraph is saying what the quoted part of the book is also explaining.

Comment: @Barmar Right, but that's what the OP is confused about.  So hopefully my re-wording will help.

Comment: *"Whitespace does not affect C++"*. pedantically, omitting space may change semantic/validity of some code `C<C<T>>` in C++03, `a++b` (vs `a + +b`) `operator ""` with MACRO concatenation (`#define M(S) "prefix"S`), ...but indeed if it `0` versus `1+` spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Both C and C++ are not affected by white space in their interpretation of the code.  That does not mean the programmer should not care about its misuse.

The best way to illustrate what the above code actually represents is to explicitly define all of the inferred braces as below. Note that the *if* statement that had no braces only has one line of code affected by the 'if then' or 'else' clause.

This is one of the reasons that people try to insist on
'good coding practices' to ensure that other people are able to clearly interpret the flow and intent of the programmer.

```
while(c != cols) {
    if(r == pad + 1 && c == pad + 1) {
        cout << greet;
        c += greet.size();
    } else {
        if(r == 0 || r == rows - 1 || c == 0 || c == cols - 1) {
            cout << "*";
        } else {
            cout << " ";
        }
        ++c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the length of indentation does not affect the interpretation of the statements. Sometimes whitespace is needed to separate characters, e.g., in `int a`. Other times it is not needed, e.g. in `a=b+c;`.

The `if` statement is defined that after the condition `if(condition)` can only be one statement.

If we want more statements we have to group them with braces {...}

Answer (score -1):

Unlike Python, C++ does not care about indentation.

But your *else* applies only on the first line. To apply to a block, it should be within { }

```
else
{
   cout << " ";
   ++c;
}
```

Indentation is not your problem here.