# How do I read a number from a file to get the size in c

Tags: c, file, fgets

For an assignment I must create 2 files each with a number that has more than 100 digits. I can do this well, but when it comes time to finding out exactly how many digits are int the file I am stumped I have tried fgets(), but I do not think that I am handling this well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int getc(FILE *stream);
int getchar(void);
```

This is not really necissary to my problem but it is part of my code eventually I will need to get the size of each number and pass them as parameters here:

```
int * add(int * a,int s_a,int * b,int s_b){
  if(s_b<s_a){
    int tmp_s;
    int * tmp_a;

    tmp_s=s_a;
    s_a=s_b;
    s_b=tmp_s;

    tmp_a=a;
    a=b;
    b=tmp_a;
  }
  int * out= (int *)malloc (sizeof(int)*(s_b+1));
  int i, carry,sum;
  carry=0;
  for(i=0;i<s_a;i++){
    sum=((a[i])+b[i]%10)+carry;
    carry=(a[i]+b[i])/10;
    out[i]=sum;
  }
  for(i;i<s_b;i++){
    sum=(b[i]+carry)%10;
    carry=(b[i]+carry)/10;
    out[i]=sum;
  }
  out[i]=carry;
  return out;

}
```

This is where  I am adding the random numbers to the file and works I do not add spaces because It is supposed to all be one very long number. Although I have the size in this function that is not the purpose of this function and the print statement will be commented out once the next function is working properly.

```
void addrandomNums(char * fileName){
  srand ( time(NULL) );
  FILE *ffp;
  ffp=fopen(fileName,"w");//if the file exsisists then we erase and write    
 new stuff
  int sizeOfNum=rand()%10000+100;//the size of the number will be from 100-10099(I think)the instructions said a number greater than 100 digits so I tried to make this as wide of a range as possible
  printf("Size of the number for this file is: %d  digits \n",sizeOfNum);
  for(int i=1;i<sizeOfNum;i++){
    fprintf(ffp,"%d", rand() % 10);//adds a number from 0-9
  }
  fclose(ffp);
}
```

This is the function that needs help I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
int getNumDigits(char * fileName){
    int numDigits=0;
    FILE *fp=fopen(fileName,"w");
    printf( "Reading the file: %s \n" ,fileName) ;
    if (fp == NULL) 
        printf("The file is not found!!");
    return 0;  
    do
    { 
        // Taking input single character at a time 
        char c = fgetc(fp); 

        // Checking for end of file 
        if (feof(fp)) 
            break ; 

        printf("%c", c); 
        numDigits++;
    }  while(1); 
    fclose(fp);
    printf("***The number of characters present in file is: %d \n",numDigits);
    //getch();
    return numDigits;
}
int main(void) {
    addrandomNums("num1.txt");

    addrandomNums("num2.txt");
    int size1=getNumDigits("num2.txt");

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all for your help this is the fixed code. I really appreciate the help.

```
 int getNumDigits(char * fileName){
     int numDigits=0;
     FILE *fp=fopen(fileName,"r");

     printf( "Reading the file: %s \n" ,fileName) ;
   //char buffer[MAX]=fgets()
   // int length=strlen(fgets(buffer, MAX, fp));
   if (fp == NULL) 
   printf("The file is not found!!");
   char c;      
   do{ 
       // Taking input single character at a time 
       c = fgetc(fp);   
       // Checking for end of file 
       if (feof(fp)){ 
         numDigits++;
         break ; 
       }
       numDigits++;
    }  while(1); 
     fclose(fp);
     printf("***The number of characters present in file is: %d \n",numDigits);
   printf("All Done.");
   return numDigits;
 }
```

Comment: Use `fgets()` to get the entire line and `strlen()` to count its length. If you want to be extra careful, you can iterate through the string using `isdigit()` to make sure you're only counting digits (e.g. you don't accidentally count the trailing newline).

Comment: Thank you would you be able to give me an example of fgets() I'm not sure that I am using it right. I thought that I was not working because I only have digits and not chars. Since I do not know the size how would I save the entire line. using malloc() ?

Comment: You're not using it ***at all***. Usage here would be to declare a `char buffer[1024]` and then `if (NULL == fgets(buffer, 1024, fp)) { /* Handle error... */ } ...`

Comment: Digits are characters, they're just always between `'0'` and `'9'`

Comment: In POSIX you can also use `getline()`. It uses `malloc()` internally to allocate the space for you, so it can handle any size line.

Comment: The problem is `return 0;` before the `do` loop. You're skipping over the code that counts the characters.

Comment: I guess you meant to put that in the `if (fp == NULL)`, but you forgot to put `{}` around the two lines.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: Thank you all for helping it really helps to have a fresh set of eyes on code. Here is the working code.

Comment: you removed the check for missing file... if a the file does not exist you will have an issue with your code. you should re-add the `return 0;` to your code just make sure it is bracketed with the `printf("The file is not found!!");` statment

Answer (score 0):

Problems with the loop:

```
                                 // problem code
int numDigits=0;
char c;      
do {                           
  c = fgetc(fp);   
  // Checking for end of file 
  if (feof(fp)){ 
    numDigits++;
    break ; 
  }
  numDigits++;
}  while(1);
```

- Off by 1

  When it is time to exit, no need to add + 1 to the count.
- Counts all characters as digits

  There is no test to determine if the character read is a digit.
- Inadequate exit condition

  On a rare input error, OP's code loop forever with `fgetc(fp)` returning `EOF` and  `feof(fp)` *not* true.
- Count may readily exceed `INT_MAX`.

---

Some fixes:

```
// int numDigits=0;
unsigned long long numDigits = 0;
unsigned long long numCharacters = 0;
//char c;      
int c;  // fgetc() typically returns 257 different values    
do { 
  c = fgetc(fp);   
  // if (feof(fp)){ 
  //  numDigits++;
  //  break ; 
  // }
  if (c == EOF) {
    break;
  } 
  // numDigits++;
  if (isdigit(c)) numDigits++;
  numCharacters++;
}  while(1);
```