# Value is being used without being initialized

Tags: c

in my code i use malloc to create n string for my project
and after that , i created 'tr' to put all of string from
**str with small letters .
and it give me an error :

> > Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'str' is being used without being initialized.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void)
{
    int n;
    char **str;
    char *tr;
    int cnt, k;
    cnt = k = NULL;
    printf("Enter number fo strings:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        str[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);

    str = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*n + 1);

    puts("Enter The strings");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)
            scanf("%s", &str[i][j]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)
        {
            if (str[i][j] >= 'a' && str[i][j] <= 'z')
                cnt++;
        }
    }

    tr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(cnt + 1));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)
        {
            if (str[i][j] >= 'a' && str[i][j] <= 'z')
                tr[k++] = str[i][j];
        }
    }

    tr[k] = NULL;
    puts(tr);
    free(tr);
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: You're doing exactly what it says you're doing. Allocate `str` before using `str[i]`. Move that allocation line up *before* you use it. Also *don't* cast `malloc`.

Comment: You first do something like `str[i] = malloc...` and on the line below you do something like `str = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*n + 1);`

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer*. It's not supposed to be used for other values. If you want to initialize `cnt` and `k` to zero, then use zero (`0`).

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> char **str;
> char *tr;
> int cnt, k;
> cnt = k = NULL;
> printf("Enter number fo strings:\n");
> scanf("%d", &n);
> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
>     str[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);  // here
> ```

you use `str` which is uninitialized. What do you expect? `str` has indeterminate value since it is uninitialized and almost certainly holds an invalid pointer value. Dereferencing an invalid pointer (which the operator `[]` does) is undefined behaviour.

What you'd have to do is first allocating memory for `str` to hold the pointers to the strings.

Btw.

> ```
> puts("Enter The strings");
> for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
> {
>     for (int j = 0; i < n; j++)
>         scanf("%s", &str[i][j]);
> }
> ```

Is also incorrect. There is no need for the inner loop to read input from stdin and store it in `str[i]`. Also, don't use `%s` without specifying a with to limit the number of characters written to the destination.

> ```
> if (str[i][j] >= 'a' && str[i][j] <= 'z')
> ```

That's what `islower()` from `<ctype>` is for.

> ```
> free(str);
> ```

That's not enough to deallocate the memory since `str` points to a number of pointers to `char` which also point to allocated memory.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    free(str[i]);
free(str);
```

to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

You have these two sections of code in the wrong order:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    str[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);

str = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*n + 1);
```

You need to allocate memory for `str` before you can assign to `str[i]`. And it should be `sizeof(char *) * n`; there's no need to add 1 to this (you only need this in `tr`, since you add a null terminator at the end).

It should be:

```
str = malloc(sizeof(char*)*n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    str[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
}
```

After

Also, please read [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You're not allocating before using, you're using *then* allocating, but also allocating incorrectly. The correct allocation is:

```
str = malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
```

Where `str` is an array of `char*`, *not* an array of `char`.

It's good that you're listening to your compiler warnings, but this one was really specific and you should be able to find the problem. Ordering of allocations is extremely important and "close enough" is not acceptable. It either works, or it's undefined behaviour.