# Trouble implementing validation using java script in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am finding it hard to use js in html as i am new to this. I have tried changing around many different things to get it to work but nothing has been successful. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried everything from changing the input types, actions, if and else if statements, alert function and many more.

```js
function validation() {
  var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
  var tel = document.getElementById('Telephone').value;
  if (Name == '' || Email == '' || Telephone == '')
    alert('action required')
  return false;
} else if (name.length < 4) {
  alert("action required")
  return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/WebForm.css">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>COM111 | WebForm | B0076234</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, inital-scale = 1.0">
  <script src="assignment2/ass2script.js"></script>
  <h1 id="h1">Welcome To My WebForm</h1>
  <h2 id="h2"> CV Request</h2>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- form -->
  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="form1">
        <div class="input-fields">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" id="name">
          <input type="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" id="Email">
          <input type="tel" class="input" placeholder="Telephone" id="Telephone">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Company" id="Telephone"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert now">
          <!--buttons-->
          <label>Short CV
<input type="radio" checked="checked">
    </label> <br>
          <label>Long CV
     <input type="radio">
    </label>
          <!-- messgebox -->
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          <div class="btn">send</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!--buttons-->
  <div id="eresult"></div>
  <!-- javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your braces don't match, it's getting a syntax error as a result.

Comment: Didn't you see the syntax error in the JavaScript console? Do you have the console open when you're trying to debug JavaScript?

Comment: Hi Barmar i am just writing the JavaScript straight into html

Comment: The `<head>` isn't supposed to contain content elements like `<h1>`.

Comment: Changing the braces did not help :(

Comment: You have other problems: You assign `name`, `email`, and `tel`, but you test `Name`, `Email`, and `Telephone`; variable names are case-sensitive.

Comment: You have `id="name"` but you use `document.getElementById("Name")`. This is also case-sensitive.

Comment: Fix all these typos and the code works.

Comment: @JackC What do you mean by that? You use the console when you're executing the code, it has nothing to do with how you write the code.

Comment: Sorry that is a silly error same with braces, unfortunately its still not working

Comment: @JackC and what about all the comments talking about the problems with the uppercase versus lowercase id and variable names? Also you say "t's still not working" ->  indeed, you haven't fixed the problem with the brace in your question, or at least there is still one. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the following problems:

1. You need braces around the block after `if`, because it contains multiple statements. See [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)
2. Add another brace at the end of the function.
3. Change `id="name"` to `id="Name"`, to match the call to `document.getElementById('Name')`.
4. Fix the variable names in the first `if` statement to match the variables that were assigned from the input values.

All of these validations can actually be implemented in the HTML itself. You can use the `required` attribute for inputs that have to be filled in, and `minlength="4"` on the `Name` input to require that it be at least 4 characters.

```js
function validation() {
  var name = document.getElementById('Name').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('Email').value;
  var tel = document.getElementById('Telephone').value;
  if (name == '' || email == '' || tel == '') {
    alert('action required')
    return false;
  } else if (name.length < 4) {
    alert("action required")
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/WebForm.css">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>COM111 | WebForm | B0076234</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, inital-scale = 1.0">
  <script src="assignment2/ass2script.js"></script>
  <h1 id="h1">Welcome To My WebForm</h1>
  <h2 id="h2"> CV Request</h2>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- form -->
  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validation()">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="form1">
        <div class="input-fields">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" id="Name">
          <input type="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" id="Email">
          <input type="tel" class="input" placeholder="Telephone" id="Telephone">
          <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Company" id="Telephone"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Insert now">
          <!--buttons-->
          <label>Short CV
<input type="radio" checked="checked">
    </label> <br>
          <label>Long CV
     <input type="radio">
    </label>
          <!-- messgebox -->
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          <div class="btn">send</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <!--buttons-->
  <div id="eresult"></div>
  <!-- javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again for the reply Barmar but i still cant seem to get it working, I am also implementing it onto html and not JavaScript

Comment: The fixes I made work, I can't tell what you're still doing wrong.

Comment: If i edit my question with the new code can you see what i am still doing wrong?

Comment: Don't remove the original code, add the new code at the end.

Comment: If your new code produces errors in the console, I'll be annoyed.

Comment: False alarm Barmar i got it working, thanks alot for your help! One issue i still have though is 'send' button is not working, i implemented the 'insert now' button just for testing because i knew my other button was not working. Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: You need to add an `onclick` handler for the DIV that calls `validation()`, and if it succeeds it then calls the form's `submit()` method.