# JavaScript Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my code:

```
var obj = null;
var voterIC = "";

$(function ()
{
  $("#btnRegister").click(function (e)
  {
    voterIC = $("#nric").val();

    if ( voterIC == "")
        $("#messageEdit").html("<h4 style=\"color:red\">Please fill in NRIC!</h4>");
    else
        obj = new Object();
        obj.NRIC = voterIC;
        obj.CreatedDate = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

    var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('voter').push().key;

    var updates = {};
    updates['/voter/' + newPostKey] = obj;

    firebase.database().ref().update(updates).then(function()
    {
      $("#messageEdit").html('<h10 style=\"color:red\"><b>Update Successfully</h10><b>');
    });
  });
});
```

Why do I get the following error and how to solve this error?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'NRIC' of null

Thank You.

Comment: You're lacking some parenthesis in the `else` branch of your `if`. Without them, only the first line `obj = new Object()` is within the else branch, while the remainder is one level up. Hence the variable `obj` is not initialized at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you have not put braces around the blocks in your `if` condition. When formatted correctly your code looks like this:

```
if (voterIC == "") {
    $("#messageEdit").html("<h4 style=\"color:red\">Please fill in NRIC!</h4>");
} else {
    obj = new Object();
}

obj.NRIC = voterIC;
obj.CreatedDate = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

Consider the case when `voterIC` is an empty string. You only set the value of `obj` to a new object when this *does not* happen. Then you continue on to try and set the `NRIC` property of the object, but due to the logic flow, it doesn't exist.

To correct the problem, put the braces around *all* statements in a conditional statement:

```
if (voterIC == "") {
  $("#messageEdit").html("<h4 style=\"color:red\">Please fill in NRIC!</h4>");
} else {
  obj = new Object();
  obj.NRIC = voterIC;
  obj.CreatedDate = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you indent the code correctly, you'll see that the `if` statement is equivalent to this:

```
if (voterIC == "")
  $("#messageEdit").html("<h4 style=\"color:red\">Please fill in NRIC!</h4>");
else
  obj = new Object();
obj.NRIC = voterIC;
obj.CreatedDate = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
```

When `voterIC == ""`, you never assign `obj`, so you get that error.

You need to put braces around the `else` block to fix this.

```
if (voterIC == "") {
  $("#messageEdit").html("<h4 style=\"color:red\">Please fill in NRIC!</h4>");
} else {
  obj = new Object();
  obj.NRIC = voterIC;
  obj.CreatedDate = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
}
```

See [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets for the else statement:

```
else{
obj = new Object();
obj.NRIC = voterIC;
obj.CreatedDate = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
}
```