# Difference between these codes in the if block

Tags: javascript

I get the expected result here.

```
 var modeObj = {};

array.forEach(num => {
    if (!modeObj[num])
        modeObj[num] = 0;
        modeObj[num]++;
});
```

I get an empty result here.

```
var modeObj = {};

array.forEach(num => {
    if (!modeObj[num]) {
        modeObj[num] = 0;
    }else {
        modeObj[num]++;
    }

});
```

How is the above code different from the one below? I'm missing some concept in the if condition.

Comment: If you indent your code correctly you might see what's wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have `if/else` - the line inside the `else` block will only gets evaluated when the value of the `if` is false.

In your first example - the second line will run every time, whether the if is valid or not.

If you don't have brackets - only the next line (after the `if`) is evaluated.
Your first example is actually the following:

```
var modeObj = {};

array.forEach(num => {
    if (!modeObj[num]) {
        modeObj[num] = 0;
    }
    modeObj[num]++;
});
```

As you can see - the `modeObj[num]++;` will get evaluated every time (not only when the `if` is true).

Answer (score 3):

The first code if condition does not have `{}`. Hence only the first line is executed and the line `modeObj[num]++;` is executed no matter what the result of the if condition is.

In the second code, you have added an else.

Answer (score 2):

You're increasing `modeObj[num]++` outside `if` part of the conditional & the second code snippet. It should be like so instead:

```
var modeObj = {};

array.forEach(num => {
    if (!modeObj[num]) {
        modeObj[num] = 0;
        modeObj[num]++;
    } else {
       // do something
    }

});
```