# Javascript if statement: Which pair of characters in this code is optional?

Tags: javascript

I've was given this is a multiple choice JS question. I said `[]`, I just wanted to check if this is correct and if not why?

Consider this if statement:

```
if (loggedIn) {
  body_classes = ["user-active"];
}
```

Which pair of characters in this code is optional?

```
""
()
{}
[]
```

Comment: No, the answer is `{}` because they are not necessary in single-line if-statements.

Comment: The braces `{}` are optional as it is a single line if statement. The brackets `[]` aren't optional because in this case they are creating a single element array.

Comment: In your question you should explain *why* you think `[]` are optional? Then we could help you understand the error.

Comment: Note that while the `{}` are optional, they're highly recommended. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: if two variables `user` and `active` exist, three are optional. If not, only two are optional, in the sense that they can be omitted but still produce valid syntax (wether they are semantically "optional" is another thing). So the answer depends on what "optional" means.

Answer (score 3):

The optional characters are the braces `{}`

```
if (loggedIn) {
  body_classes = ["user-active"];
}
```

is the same as

```
if (loggedIn)
  body_classes = ["user-active"];
```

If you remove the square brackets then `body_classes` becomes a string rather than an array.