# How do I reverse a specific row of a multidimensional array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, reverse, function-definition

I have a multidimensional array with 3 rows and 4 columns. The program should use `reverseRow()`function to reverse a specific row from an array. Like, let's say user's input is 2, then it should reverse second row and print it.

I have tried a swap method, but it didn't work. I also tried using pointers, but it didn't work as well. Can someone explain it for me? How do I reverse a specific row?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int arr[3][4] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9, 10, 11, 12}};
int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

void reverseRow(int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int temp = arr[low][0];
        arr[low][0] = arr[high][0];
        arr[high][0] = temp;

        reverseRow(low + 1, high - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 3; i > 0; j--)
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    }
}

void printMenu()
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("You can choose one of these services: \n");
    printf("1. Get the elements of a specific row reversed \n");
    printf("Please select one to try ");
    int answer;
    scanf("%d", &answer);

    switch (answer)
    {

    case 1:
        reverseRow(0, n - 1);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Bye!\n");
        break;

    default:
        printf("please select carefully! \n");
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    printMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Please, use your code editors "indent code", "format document", … functionality to indent your code – that makes it both easier to read for us (significantly so! This is a bit of a mess!), it also helps you see bugs yourself. Professional programmers use that functionality *all the time*, and will reject code that was not machine-formatted, because they don't trust themselves to see bugs without that. And for beginners, it's twice as important!

Comment: radicalEd, Are you trying to reverse a row or the first column?

Comment: To me, it looks like you have an array with *3* rows and *4* columns, and a function that reverses the first *column*, but then displays the contents of each row one after another on one line.

Comment: okay, I will edit the code. Thank you for the helpful information.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I am trying to reverse a specific row. LIke, if user's input is 2, then second row should be reversed.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1

Comment: Take a smaller bite. Can you write a function that, given an array of specified length, reverses that one array ? Seems you can (sort of).. So, then realize all you're asking to do is the same, just for a specific array in an array of arrays.

Comment: Why does the function take 2 arguments? Is it supposed to reverse all the rows in a range?

Comment: I realized the question was unclear, so I edited it.

Comment: @radicalEd And where is there the function that reverses a row? I do not see such a function.

Comment: You're swapping the first element of two different rows. You're not reversing anything.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow to be honest Im very confused. The "reverseRow" function is suppose to reverse it, but as I said it doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar oh, thank you for pointing that out. I will try changing the code.

Comment: Where do you ask the user for the row number to reverse? What are `low` and `high` supposed to be?

Comment: The menu says that option 4 is for reversing, but you call the function with option 1.

Comment: @Barmar I changed menu so I can reduce the code size in the question.

Comment: You still never ask the user for the row number to reverse. Why is it always `0` and `n-1`?

Comment: some parts of code that do not affect this 'reversing' were removed before I uploaded the question.

Comment: for '0' and 'n-1' it is just one kind of solution I saw. But it doesn't work, so Im asking for help here

Comment: Are `high` and `low` supposed to be column numbers to swap? You also need the row number as a parameter.

Comment: @Barmar hey. Thank you for your solution, but it crashed. I think it's because it is infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're reversing the first column, not a user-selected row.

You're not passing the row number to the function.

The loop that prints the array is printing all the columns in reverse order, and it's using `n` as the number of rows, not columns. I've renamed the variables to be clearer and fixed the printing loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arr[3][4] = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9, 10, 11, 12}};
int rows = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
int cols = sizeof(arr[0]) / sizeof(arr[0][0]);

void reverseRow(int rownum, int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int temp = arr[rownum][low];
        arr[rownum][low] = arr[rownum][high];
        arr[rownum][high] = temp;

        reverseRow(rownum, low + 1, high - 1);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void printMenu()
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("You can choose one of these services: \n");
    printf("1. Get the elements of a specific row reversed \n");
    printf("Please select one to try ");
    int answer;
    scanf("%d", &answer);

    switch (answer)
    {

    case 1:
        printf("Please select row number: ");
        int row;
        scanf("%d", &row);
        if (row >= rows || row < 0) {
            printf("Invalid row\n");
            break;
        }
        reverseRow(row, 0, cols - 1);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Bye!\n");
        break;

    default:
        printf("please select carefully! \n");
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{

    printMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution did reversed specific row, which is great, but then it reversed row before itself and ended up with Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: The problem was in your code that prints the array, it has the wrong limits in the indexes. I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 0):

What is the row of a two-dimensional array?

It is a one dimensional array.

So what you need is to write a function that reverses a one-dimensional array.

An iterative function can look the following way

```
void reverseRow( int *a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n-i-1];
        a[n-i-1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

A recursive function can look the following way

```
void reverseRow( int *a, size_t n )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        int tmp = a[0];
        a[0] = a[n-1];
        a[n-1] = tmp;

        reverseRow( a + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}
```

And either function is called like for example

```
reverseRow( arr[1], 4 );
```

that reverses the second row of the original array.

Or if the number of row (starting from 0) is stored in some variable as for example row then the function is called like

```
reverseRow( arr[row], 4 );
```

To output the reversed row you need to write a separate function.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverseRowIterative( int *a, size_t n )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
    {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[n - i - 1];
        a[n - i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}

void reverseRowRecursive( int *a, size_t n )
{
    if (!( n < 2 ))
    {
        int tmp = a[0];
        a[0] = a[n - 1];
        a[n - 1] = tmp;

        reverseRowRecursive( a + 1, n - 2 );
    }
}

void printRow( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf( "%2d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { M = 3, N = 4 };

    int arr[M][N] = 
    {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4 },
        { 5,  6,  7,  8 },
        { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        reverseRowIterative( arr[i], N );
        printRow( arr[i], N );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        reverseRowRecursive( arr[i], N );
        printRow( arr[i], N );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
 4  3  2  1
 8  7  6  5
12 11 10  9

 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
```