# Why does this code work but the other version does not?

Tags: c, loops, kernighan-and-ritchie

Specifically, the code is a solution to **Exercise 1-9** in K&R *C Programming Language 2nd Edition*. I already solved it, but I have a question.

> Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

This code works and returns the desired output

```
int ch, last;

for (last = 0; (ch = getchar()) != EOF; last = ch)
    if (ch == ' ' && last == ' ')
        ;
    else
        putchar(ch);
```

This version of the code doesn't work and instead prints literally the same input with excess spaces included.

```
int ch, last;
last = 0;

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
    if (ch == ' ' && last == ' ')
        ;
    else
        putchar(ch);
    
    last = ch;
```

Could somebody tell me the difference between these two versions of code and why the latter version doesn't work?

Comment: Note that indentation doesn't matter here; the contents of both loops are simply the one following statement (in both instances, just an if statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2nd version you need to place the body of the while loop in a {} as it consist of two statements (`if` and `last=` assignment).  Otherwise only the first statement is executed in the loop, and the 2nd after the loop terminates.

```
int ch, last;
last = 0;

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (ch == ' ' && last == ' ')
        ;
    else
        putchar(ch);
    
    last = ch;
}
```

I would invert the condition:

```
    if (ch != ' ' || last != ' ')
        putchar(ch);
```

Answer (score 4):

`last = ch;` is not inside the loop, so you're not setting it until after you've read the entire file. So you're comparing with `0` every time.

If you want to have multiple statements in a loop, you have to put `{}` around them.

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (ch == ' ' && last == ' ') {
    } else {
        putchar(ch);
    }
    last = ch;
}
```

This is a perfect example of [Why is it considered a bad practice to omit curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The answers about **curly braces** are correct.

There is, however, another way to transform the `for()` expression into a `while()` loop without an abundance of *filigree* in the code.

Below traversing a string stands in for getting characters from stdin.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *str = " Once upon   a   time  in a land   far  away    ";

    int i = 0, ch, last = 0;
    while( (ch = str[i++]) != '\0' )
        if ( ch != ' ' || last != ' ' )
            putchar( last = ch ); // NB: copy value

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
" Once upon a time in a land far away " // quotes added to show SPs
```

(Shameless duplication of @Alan Wind's observation about boolean logic.)

Comment: Imitation is flattery :-)

Comment: @AllanWind Take a bow. You earned it. `:-)` To build every conceivable logic cct from a box of NOR gates was my boyhood ambition... `:-)`